# Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding, decimal-point

I have this line of code which rounds my numbers to two decimal places. But I get numbers like this: 10.8, 2.4, etc. These are not my idea of two decimal places so how I can improve the following?

```
Math.round(price*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
```

I want numbers like 10.80, 2.40, etc. Use of jQuery is fine with me.

Comment: Your code is exactly what I was looking for(to reduce float precision to 7 decimal places for smaller JSON file) Skipping Math.pow for speed val = Math.round(val * 10000000) / 10000000);

Comment: As the [currently-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1726662/157247) gives arguably a wrong result for a broad range of values thanks to aggravating imprecision inherent in the numbers (`0.565`, `0.575`, `1.005`), can I suggest looking again at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21323330/157247), which gets them correct?

Comment: Maybe you want to include an sprintf library for JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format

Comment: After correctly rounding with the decimal place shifting and rounding method, you could use the [`number.toFixed(x)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) method to convert it to a string with the required amount of zeroes. E.g. round `1.34` to `1.3` with the cross-browser method then add 1 zero and convert to string with `1.3.toFixed(2)` (to get `"1.30"`).

Comment: It's 2020 and there is no simple native way in JavaScript to simply round a number. wow.

Comment: const formattedNumber = Math.round(number * 100) / 100;

Answer (score 1151, accepted):

To format a number using fixed-point notation, you can simply use the [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```
(10.8).toFixed(2); // "10.80"

var num = 2.4;
alert(num.toFixed(2)); // "2.40"
```

Note that `toFixed()` returns a string.

**IMPORTANT**: Note that toFixed does not round 90% of the time, it will return the rounded value, but for many cases, it doesn't work.

For instance:

`2.005.toFixed(2) === "2.00"`

## UPDATE:

Nowadays, you can use the [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) constructor. It's part of the [ECMAScript Internationalization API Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma402/) (ECMA402). It has [pretty good browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=NumberFormat), including even IE11, and it is [fully supported in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html).

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
   maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});

console.log(formatter.format(2.005)); // "2.01"
console.log(formatter.format(1.345)); // "1.35"
```

You can alternatively use the `toLocaleString` method, which internally will use the `Intl` API:

```js
const format = (num, decimals) => num.toLocaleString('en-US', {
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
   maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});


console.log(format(2.005)); // "2.01"
console.log(format(1.345)); // "1.35"
```

This API also provides you a wide variety of options to format, like thousand separators, currency symbols, etc.

Comment: Doesn't work consistently across all browsers, ie `(0.09).toFixed(1);` gives 0.0 in IE8

Comment: fixed doesn't round, you can do it first:

(Math.round(0.09)).toFixed(1);

Comment: @rekans: This is wrong. `Math.Round(0.09)` will return `0` so this will always give `0.0`...

Comment: Also toFixed does round. In both firefox and IE `(0.19).toFixed(1)` gives a result of `0.2`

Comment: This is a bad idea in most situations, it converts the number to a string or float point number in some cases.

Comment: Have to agree with @AshBlue here... this is only safe for formatting presentation of values.  May break code with further calculations.  Otherwise `Math.round(value*100)/100` works better for 2DP.

Comment: Still bad idea (Math.round(1.275*100)/100).toFixed(2) is 1.27 not 1.28

Comment: use 'Math.round((num + 0.00001) * 100) / 100'

Comment: @rekans: toFixed also rounds the number. You can try doing this for example
(34629.29/1000).toFixed(2) and see that it returns 34.63, which is already rounded to 2 decimal points

Comment: One thing to be kept in mine is that `.toFixed` is not always reliable when talking about accuracy. For example, `1.345.toFixed(2)` yields a result of `"1.34"` which is not correct. A better way to do is by `Math.round(1.345*100)/100 //1.35`.

Comment: Just put your attention that if you use toFixed() method you will get

typeof 0.123.toFixed(2) 
"string"

So you should remember about parsing of obtained string

Comment: Remember that (0.00001).toFixed(2) returns 0.00 without rounding. You will loose your number.

Comment: use the update format, pretty much an exact equivalent to number_format(2) in php

Answer (score 114):

This is an old topic but still top-ranked Google results and the solutions offered share the same floating point decimals issue. Here is the (very generic) function I use, [thanks to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Example:_Decimal_rounding):

```
function round(value, exp) {
  if (typeof exp === 'undefined' || +exp === 0)
    return Math.round(value);

  value = +value;
  exp = +exp;

  if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === 'number' && exp % 1 === 0))
    return NaN;

  // Shift
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  value = Math.round(+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp)));

  // Shift back
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp));
}
```

As we can see, we don't get these issues:

```
round(1.275, 2);   // Returns 1.28
round(1.27499, 2); // Returns 1.27
```

This genericity also provides some cool stuff:

```
round(1234.5678, -2);   // Returns 1200
round(1.2345678e+2, 2); // Returns 123.46
round("123.45");        // Returns 123
```

---

Now, to answer the OP's question, one has to type:

```
round(10.8034, 2).toFixed(2); // Returns "10.80"
round(10.8, 2).toFixed(2);    // Returns "10.80"
```

---

Or, for a more concise, less generic function:

```
function round2Fixed(value) {
  value = +value;

  if (isNaN(value))
    return NaN;

  // Shift
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  value = Math.round(+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + 2) : 2)));

  // Shift back
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  return (+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - 2) : -2))).toFixed(2);
}
```

You can call it with:

```
round2Fixed(10.8034); // Returns "10.80"
round2Fixed(10.8);    // Returns "10.80"
```

---

Various examples and tests (thanks to [**@t-j-crowder**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)!):

```js
function round(value, exp) {
  if (typeof exp === 'undefined' || +exp === 0)
    return Math.round(value);

  value = +value;
  exp = +exp;

  if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === 'number' && exp % 1 === 0))
    return NaN;

  // Shift
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  value = Math.round(+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp)));

  // Shift back
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp));
}
function naive(value, exp) {
  if (!exp) {
    return Math.round(value);
  }
  var pow = Math.pow(10, exp);
  return Math.round(value * pow) / pow;
}
function test(val, places) {
  subtest(val, places);
  val = typeof val === "string" ? "-" + val : -val;
  subtest(val, places);
}
function subtest(val, places) {
  var placesOrZero = places || 0;
  var naiveResult = naive(val, places);
  var roundResult = round(val, places);
  if (placesOrZero >= 0) {
    naiveResult = naiveResult.toFixed(placesOrZero);
    roundResult = roundResult.toFixed(placesOrZero);
  } else {
    naiveResult = naiveResult.toString();
    roundResult = roundResult.toString();
  }
  $("<tr>")
    .append($("<td>").text(JSON.stringify(val)))
    .append($("<td>").text(placesOrZero))
    .append($("<td>").text(naiveResult))
    .append($("<td>").text(roundResult))
    .appendTo("#results");
}
test(0.565, 2);
test(0.575, 2);
test(0.585, 2);
test(1.275, 2);
test(1.27499, 2);
test(1234.5678, -2);
test(1.2345678e+2, 2);
test("123.45");
test(10.8034, 2);
test(10.8, 2);
test(1.005, 2);
test(1.0005, 2);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
td, th {
  padding: 4px;
}
th {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
td {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Places</th>
      <th>Naive</th>
      <th>Thorough</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results">
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How is there not a simple way to do this? ES6 to the rescue?

Comment: Thank you for posting the MDN polyfill. On the linked MDN page the polyfill is no longer there. I wonder why it was removed...

Comment: How can I use it to get value upto first decimal place,like 3.0421 shuld return 3.0?

Comment: @RIni, you should be able to use `round(3.0421, 1)` to get `3` as a number or `round(3.0421, 1).toFixed(1)` to get `'3.0'` as a string.

Answer (score 45):

I usually add this to my personal library, and after some suggestions and using the @TIMINeutron solution too, and making it adaptable for decimal length then, this one fits best:

```
function precise_round(num, decimals) {
   var t = Math.pow(10, decimals);   
   return (Math.round((num * t) + (decimals>0?1:0)*(Math.sign(num) * (10 / Math.pow(100, decimals)))) / t).toFixed(decimals);
}
```

will work for the exceptions reported.

Comment: precise_round(1.275,2) is 1.27?

Comment: precise_round(6,2) returns 6 (no decimals as asked in the question)

Comment: @Imre Change the return value to (Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,decimals))/Math.pow(10,decimals)).toFixed(2); and you will no longer have that issue.

Comment: @dkroy Nice idea, although the argument for `toFixed(...)` should be `decimals`, as in the [answer by @TIMINeutron](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16319855/706714)

Comment: @Imre my mistake, not sure why I inserted two.

Comment: where do you declare "sign" and "dec"  if your second function is picked up as is shouldn't it have them as undefined?

Comment: You're doing the power calculation twice. Isn't it better to do it once and store the result?

Comment: Does not work in IE 11, because **Math** has no method **sign** here.

Comment: I've added a workarround for missign sign method in IE: https://gist.github.com/ArminVieweg/28647e735aa6efaba401

Comment: @Armin Your fix also makes it work in Safari.  The original function did not work in Safari.

Comment: Please note that this returns a string. To return a decimal again, wrap the return value in parseFloat() ...

Answer (score 23):

## FAST AND EASY

```js
parseFloat(number.toFixed(2))
```

### Example

```js
let number = 2.55435930

let roundedString = number.toFixed(2)    // "2.55"

let twoDecimalsNumber = parseFloat(roundedString)    // 2.55

let directly = parseFloat(number.toFixed(2))    // 2.55
```

Comment: after searching for some time, finally this worked with me, simple and easy

Comment: Yes, with caveats mentioned above about toFixed, which can return inaccurate roundings for stuff like 1.005. You SHOULD mention those caveats in your answer.

Comment: parseFloat(13.99999).toFixed(2)
> "14.00"
parseFloat(parseFloat(13.99999).toFixed(2))
> 14

Answer (score 20):

One way to be 100% sure that you get a number with 2 decimals:

```
(Math.round(num*100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

If this causes rounding errors, you can use the following as James has explained in his comment:

```
(Math.round((num * 1000)/10)/100).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: This is the best, simplest way to do it. However, due to floating point math, 1.275 * 100 = 127.49999999999999, which could cause minor errors in the rounding. To fix this, we can multiply by 1000 and divide by 10, as (1.275 * 1000)/10 = 127.5. As follows:



`var answer = (Math.round((num * 1000)/10)/100).toFixed(2);`

Comment: (Math.round((1.015 * 1000)/10)/100).toFixed(2) still gives 1.01, shouldn't it be 1.02 ?

Comment: `(Math.round((99999999999999.9999 * 1000)/10)/100).toFixed(4)` returns
`"100000000000000.0000"`

Answer (score 18):

I don't know why can't I add a comment to a previous answer (maybe I'm hopelessly blind, I don't know), but I came up with a solution using @Miguel's answer:

```
function precise_round(num,decimals) {
   return Math.round(num*Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
}
```

And its two comments (from @bighostkim and @Imre):

- Problem with `precise_round(1.275,2)` not returning 1.28
- Problem with `precise_round(6,2)` not returning 6.00 (as he wanted).

My final solution is as follows:

```
function precise_round(num,decimals) {
    var sign = num >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
    return (Math.round((num*Math.pow(10,decimals)) + (sign*0.001)) / Math.pow(10,decimals)).toFixed(decimals);
}
```

As you can see I had to add a little bit of "correction" (it's not what it is, but since Math.round is lossy - you can check it on jsfiddle.net - this is the only way I knew how to "fix" it). It adds 0.001 to the already padded number, so it is adding a `1` three `0`s to the right of the decimal value. So it should be safe to use.

After that I added `.toFixed(decimal)` to always output the number in the correct format (with the right amount of decimals).

So that's pretty much it. Use it well ;)

EDIT: added functionality to the "correction" of negative numbers.

Comment: The "correction" is *mostly* safe, but e.g. `precise_round(1.27499,2)` now also returns 1.28... It's not `Math.round` that is lossy; the way that computers internally store floating point values is. Basically, you're doomed to fail with some values before the data even gets to your function :)

Comment: @Imre, you're absolutelly right. That's why I explain what is this 0.001 doing there, in case anyone wants to make it "more _precise_" or even delete it (if you happen to have a super computer with 2 Mbytes per float, wich I don't think anyone here does ;)

Comment: Actually, the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) is pretty specific about using 64 bits for number values, so having/using a supercomputer wouldn't change anything :)

Comment: for the 0.001 you can replace by adding many zeros according to length of the decimals. so..

Answer (score 14):

> toFixed(n) provides n length after the decimal point; toPrecision(x)
>   provides x total length.

Use this method below

```
// Example: toPrecision(4) when the number has 7 digits (3 before, 4 after)
    // It will round to the tenths place
    num = 500.2349;
    result = num.toPrecision(4); // result will equal 500.2
```

AND if you want the number to be fixed use

```
result = num.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: it does not work well...
for number num = 50.2349 you should write toPrecision(3) to get 50.2

Comment: its just an example you can change it as per your need @PiotrCzyż

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find an accurate solution for this problem, so I created my own:

```
function inprecise_round(value, decPlaces) {
  return Math.round(value*Math.pow(10,decPlaces))/Math.pow(10,decPlaces);
}

function precise_round(value, decPlaces){
    var val = value * Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
    var fraction = (Math.round((val-parseInt(val))*10)/10);

    //this line is for consistency with .NET Decimal.Round behavior
    // -342.055 => -342.06
    if(fraction == -0.5) fraction = -0.6;

    val = Math.round(parseInt(val) + fraction) / Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
    return val;
}
```

Examples:

```js
function inprecise_round(value, decPlaces) {
  return Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, decPlaces)) / Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
}

function precise_round(value, decPlaces) {
  var val = value * Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
  var fraction = (Math.round((val - parseInt(val)) * 10) / 10);

  //this line is for consistency with .NET Decimal.Round behavior
  // -342.055 => -342.06
  if (fraction == -0.5) fraction = -0.6;

  val = Math.round(parseInt(val) + fraction) / Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
  return val;
}

// This may produce different results depending on the browser environment
console.log("342.055.toFixed(2)         :", 342.055.toFixed(2)); // 342.06 on Chrome & IE10

console.log("inprecise_round(342.055, 2):", inprecise_round(342.055, 2)); // 342.05
console.log("precise_round(342.055, 2)  :", precise_round(342.055, 2));   // 342.06
console.log("precise_round(-342.055, 2) :", precise_round(-342.055, 2));  // -342.06

console.log("inprecise_round(0.565, 2)  :", inprecise_round(0.565, 2));   // 0.56
console.log("precise_round(0.565, 2)    :", precise_round(0.565, 2));     // 0.57
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's a ditty to test this: http://jsfiddle.net/lamarant/ySXuF/. I'm applying toFixed() to the value prior to returning it which appends the correct number of zeroes to the end of the returned value.

Comment: not working for 
value=0,004990845956707237 and 
inprecise_round(value,8) 
returns 0,00499085 but it must return 0,00499084

Comment: inprecise_round(9.999, 2) give 10 where it needs to be 9.99

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple one

```
function roundFloat(num,dec){
    var d = 1;
    for (var i=0; i<dec; i++){
        d += "0";
    }
    return Math.round(num * d) / d;
}
```

Use like `alert(roundFloat(1.79209243929,4));`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow3n/YqQgC/)

Answer (score 4):

**Round down**

```
function round_down(value, decPlaces) {
    return Math.floor(value * Math.pow(10, decPlaces)) / Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
}
```

**Round up**

```
function round_up(value, decPlaces) {
    return Math.ceil(value * Math.pow(10, decPlaces)) / Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
}
```

**Round nearest**

```
function round_nearest(value, decPlaces) {
    return Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, decPlaces)) / Math.pow(10, decPlaces);
}
```

> Merged https://stackoverflow.com/a/7641824/1889449 and
>   https://www.kirupa.com/html5/rounding_numbers_in_javascript.htm Thanks
>   them.

Answer (score 4):

Building on top of [*Christian C. Salvadó's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726662/7974948), doing the following will output a `Number` type, and also seems to be dealing with rounding well:

```
const roundNumberToTwoDecimalPlaces = (num) => Number(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
}).format(num));

roundNumberToTwoDecimalPlaces(1.344); // => 1.34
roundNumberToTwoDecimalPlaces(1.345); // => 1.35
```

The difference between the above and what has already been mentioned is that you don't need the `.format()` chaining when you're using it[, and that it outputs a `Number` type].

Comment: This returns NaN

Comment: what was the input? @Bowis

Answer (score 3):

@heridev and I created a small function in jQuery.

You can try next:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="one" class="two-digits"><br>
<input type="text" name="two" class="two-digits">​
```

jQuery

```
// apply the two-digits behaviour to elements with 'two-digits' as their class
$( function() {
    $('.two-digits').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().indexOf('.')!=-1){         
            if($(this).val().split(".")[1].length > 2){                
                if( isNaN( parseFloat( this.value ) ) ) return;
                this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
            }  
         }            
         return this; //for chaining
    });
});
```

​
DEMO ONLINE:

http://jsfiddle.net/c4Wqn/

Comment: I can appreciate the contribution, though I think adding DOM elements and jQuery into the mix seems out of the scope of the question.

Comment: You shouldn't listen to the keyup event, as it looks verry bad and doesn't activate when you add something with script. I'd rather listen to the `input` event. This doesn't create a flickering effect and also fires when you access the field with JS

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with floating point values is that they are trying to represent an infinite amount of (continuous) values with a fixed amount of bits. So naturally, there must be some loss in play, and you're going to be bitten with some values.

When a computer stores 1.275 as a floating point value, it won't actually remember whether it was 1.275 or 1.27499999999999993, or even 1.27500000000000002. These values should give different results after rounding to two decimals, but they won't, since for computer they look *exactly the same* after storing as floating point values, and there's no way to restore the lost data. Any further calculations will only accumulate such imprecision.

So, if precision matters, you have to avoid floating point values from the start. The simplest options are to

- use a [devoted library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2622144/706714)
- use strings for storing and passing around the values (accompanied by string operations)
- use integers (e.g. you could be passing around the amount of hundredths of your actual value, e.g. amount in cents instead of amount in dollars)

For example, when using integers to store the number of hundredths, the function for finding the actual value is quite simple:

```
function descale(num, decimals) {
    var hasMinus = num < 0;
    var numString = Math.abs(num).toString();
    var precedingZeroes = '';
    for (var i = numString.length; i <= decimals; i++) {
        precedingZeroes += '0';
    }
    numString = precedingZeroes + numString;
    return (hasMinus ? '-' : '') 
        + numString.substr(0, numString.length-decimals) 
        + '.' 
        + numString.substr(numString.length-decimals);
}

alert(descale(127, 2));
```

With strings, you'll need rounding, but it's still manageable:

```
function precise_round(num, decimals) {
    var parts = num.split('.');
    var hasMinus = parts.length > 0 && parts[0].length > 0 && parts[0].charAt(0) == '-';
    var integralPart = parts.length == 0 ? '0' : (hasMinus ? parts[0].substr(1) : parts[0]);
    var decimalPart = parts.length > 1 ? parts[1] : '';
    if (decimalPart.length > decimals) {
        var roundOffNumber = decimalPart.charAt(decimals);
        decimalPart = decimalPart.substr(0, decimals);
        if ('56789'.indexOf(roundOffNumber) > -1) {
            var numbers = integralPart + decimalPart;
            var i = numbers.length;
            var trailingZeroes = '';
            var justOneAndTrailingZeroes = true;
            do {
                i--;
                var roundedNumber = '1234567890'.charAt(parseInt(numbers.charAt(i)));
                if (roundedNumber === '0') {
                    trailingZeroes += '0';
                } else {
                    numbers = numbers.substr(0, i) + roundedNumber + trailingZeroes;
                    justOneAndTrailingZeroes = false;
                    break;
                }
            } while (i > 0);
            if (justOneAndTrailingZeroes) {
                numbers = '1' + trailingZeroes;
            }
            integralPart = numbers.substr(0, numbers.length - decimals);
            decimalPart = numbers.substr(numbers.length - decimals);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = decimalPart.length; i < decimals; i++) {
            decimalPart += '0';
        }
    }
    return (hasMinus ? '-' : '') + integralPart + (decimals > 0 ? '.' + decimalPart : '');
}

alert(precise_round('1.275', 2));
alert(precise_round('1.27499999999999993', 2));
```

Note that this function rounds to nearest, *ties away from zero*, while [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) recommends rounding to nearest, *ties to even* as the default behavior for floating point operations. Such modifications are left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: `precise_round("999999999999999999.9999", 2)` returns
`"1000000000000000000.00"`

Comment: I want it to be `999999999999999999.99`

Comment: @FaizanHussainRabbani 1000000000000000000.00 is the correct result for this rounding - 9.9999 is much closer to 10.00 than 9.99. Rounding is a function defined in mathematics and standardized for computing in IEEE 754. If you want a different result, you need a different function. Write the tests to specify what results you need for various inputs, and write code that would satisfy those tests.

Answer (score 2):

Round your decimal value, then use `toFixed(x)` for your expected digit(s).

```
function parseDecimalRoundAndFixed(num,dec){
  var d =  Math.pow(10,dec);
  return (Math.round(num * d) / d).toFixed(dec);
}
```

---

Call

parseDecimalRoundAndFixed(10.800243929,4)  =>  10.80
parseDecimalRoundAndFixed(10.807243929,2)  =>  10.81

Answer (score 2):

```
Number(Math.round(1.005+'e2')+'e-2'); // 1.01
```

This worked for me: [Rounding Decimals in JavaScript](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

With these examples you will still get an error when trying to round the number 1.005 the solution is to either use a library like Math.js or this function:

```
function round(value: number, decimals: number) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}
```

Comment: Turns 9.90 into 9.9

Answer (score 2):

In general, decimal rounding is done by scaling: `round(num * p) / p`

**Naive implementation**

Using the following function with halfway numbers, you will get either the upper rounded value as expected, or the lower rounded value sometimes depending on the input.

This `inconsistency` in rounding may introduce hard to detect bugs in the client code.

```js
function naiveRound(num, decimalPlaces) {
    var p = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return Math.round(num * p) / p;
}

console.log( naiveRound(1.245, 2) );  // 1.25 correct (rounded as expected)
console.log( naiveRound(1.255, 2) );  // 1.25 incorrect (should be 1.26)
```

**Better implementations**

By converting the number to a string in the **exponential notation**, positive numbers are rounded as expected.
But, be aware that negative numbers round differently than positive numbers.

In fact, it performs what is basically equivalent to ["round half up"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) as the rule, you will see that `round(-1.005, 2)` evaluates to `-1` even though `round(1.005, 2)` evaluates to `1.01`. The [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#round) _.round method uses this technique.

```js
/**
 * Round half up ('round half towards positive infinity')
 * Uses exponential notation to avoid floating-point issues.
 * Negative numbers round differently than positive numbers.
 */
function round(num, decimalPlaces) {
    num = Math.round(num + "e" + decimalPlaces);
    return Number(num + "e" + -decimalPlaces);
}

// test rounding of half
console.log( round(0.5, 0) );  // 1
console.log( round(-0.5, 0) ); // 0

// testing edge cases
console.log( round(1.005, 2) );   // 1.01
console.log( round(2.175, 2) );   // 2.18
console.log( round(5.015, 2) );   // 5.02

console.log( round(-1.005, 2) );  // -1
console.log( round(-2.175, 2) );  // -2.17
console.log( round(-5.015, 2) );  // -5.01
```

If you want the usual behavior when rounding negative numbers, you would need to convert negative numbers to positive before calling [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), and then convert them back to negative numbers before returning.

```
// Round half away from zero
function round(num, decimalPlaces) {
    num = Math.round(Math.abs(num) + "e" + decimalPlaces) * Math.sign(num);
    return Number(num + "e" + -decimalPlaces);
}
```

There is a different purely mathematical technique to perform round-to-nearest (using ["round half away from zero"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero)), in which **epsilon correction** is applied before calling the rounding function.

Simply, we add the smallest possible float value (= 1.0 ulp; unit in the last place) to the number before rounding. This moves to the next representable value after the number, away from zero.

```js
/**
 * Round half away from zero ('commercial' rounding)
 * Uses correction to offset floating-point inaccuracies.
 * Works symmetrically for positive and negative numbers.
 */
function round(num, decimalPlaces) {
    var p = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    var e = Number.EPSILON * num * p;
    return Math.round((num * p) + e) / p;
}

// test rounding of half
console.log( round(0.5, 0) );  // 1
console.log( round(-0.5, 0) ); // -1

// testing edge cases
console.log( round(1.005, 2) );  // 1.01
console.log( round(2.175, 2) );  // 2.18
console.log( round(5.015, 2) );  // 5.02

console.log( round(-1.005, 2) ); // -1.01
console.log( round(-2.175, 2) ); // -2.18
console.log( round(-5.015, 2) ); // -5.02
```

This is needed to offset the implicit [round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) that may occur during encoding of decimal numbers, particularly those  having "5" in the last decimal position, like 1.005, 2.675 and 16.235. Actually, `1.005` in decimal system is encoded to `1.0049999999999999` in 64-bit binary float; while, `1234567.005` in decimal system is encoded to `1234567.0049999998882413` in 64-bit binary float.

It is worth noting that the maximum binary `round-off error` is dependent upon (1) the magnitude of the number and (2) the relative machine epsilon (2^-52).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my 1-line solution: **`Number((yourNumericValueHere).toFixed(2));`**

Here's what happens:

1) First, you apply `.toFixed(2)` onto the number that you want to round off the decimal places of. Note that this will convert the value to a string from number. So if you are using Typescript, it will throw an error like this:

"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'"

2) To get back the numeric value or to convert the string to numeric value, simply apply the `Number()` function on that so-called 'string' value.

For clarification, look at the example below:

**EXAMPLE:**
I have an amount that has upto 5 digits in the decimal places and I would like to shorten it to upto 2 decimal places. I do it like so:

```js
var price = 0.26453;
var priceRounded = Number((price).toFixed(2));
console.log('Original Price: ' + price);
console.log('Price Rounded: ' + priceRounded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put **the following** in some global scope:

```
Number.prototype.getDecimals = function ( decDigCount ) {
   return this.toFixed(decDigCount);
}
```

and **then try**:

```
var a = 56.23232323;
a.getDecimals(2); // will return 56.23
```

### Update

Note that `toFixed()` can only work for the number of decimals between `0-20` i.e. `a.getDecimals(25)` may generate a javascript error, so to accomodate that you may add some additional check i.e.

```
Number.prototype.getDecimals = function ( decDigCount ) {
   return ( decDigCount > 20 ) ? this : this.toFixed(decDigCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Number(((Math.random() * 100) + 1).toFixed(2))
```

this will return a random number from 1 to 100 rounded to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Using this response by reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029698/454827

I build a function to get dynamic numbers of decimals:

```
function toDec(num, dec)
{
        if(typeof dec=='undefined' || dec<0)
                dec = 2;

        var tmp = dec + 1;
        for(var i=1; i<=tmp; i++)
                num = num * 10;

        num = num / 10;
        num = Math.round(num);
        for(var i=1; i<=dec; i++)
                num = num / 10;

        num = num.toFixed(dec);

        return num;
}
```

here working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wpxLduLc/

Answer (score 1):

```js
parse = function (data) {
       data = Math.round(data*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
       if (data != null) {
            var lastone = data.toString().split('').pop();
            if (lastone != '.') {
                 data = parseFloat(data);
            }
       }
       return data;
  };

$('#result').html(parse(200)); // output 200
$('#result1').html(parse(200.1)); // output 200.1
$('#result2').html(parse(200.10)); // output 200.1
$('#result3').html(parse(200.109)); // output 200.11
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got some ideas from this post a few months back, but none of the answers here, nor answers from other posts/blogs could handle all the scenarios (e.g. negative numbers and some "lucky numbers" our tester found). In the end, our tester did not find any problem with this method below. Pasting a snippet of my code:

```
fixPrecision: function (value) {
    var me = this,
        nan = isNaN(value),
        precision = me.decimalPrecision;

    if (nan || !value) {
        return nan ? '' : value;
    } else if (!me.allowDecimals || precision <= 0) {
        precision = 0;
    }

    //[1]
    //return parseFloat(Ext.Number.toFixed(parseFloat(value), precision));
    precision = precision || 0;
    var negMultiplier = value < 0 ? -1 : 1;

    //[2]
    var numWithExp = parseFloat(value + "e" + precision);
    var roundedNum = parseFloat(Math.round(Math.abs(numWithExp)) + 'e-' + precision) * negMultiplier;
    return parseFloat(roundedNum.toFixed(precision));
},
```

I also have code comments (sorry i forgot all the details already)...I'm posting my answer here for future reference:

```
9.995 * 100 = 999.4999999999999
Whereas 9.995e2 = 999.5
This discrepancy causes Math.round(9.995 * 100) = 999 instead of 1000.
Use e notation instead of multiplying /dividing by Math.Pow(10,precision).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Math.round((10.2)*100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

That should yield: `10.20`

```
(Math.round((.05)*100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

That should yield: `0.05`

```
(Math.round((4.04)*100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

That should yield: `4.04`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fix the problem the modifier.
***Support 2 decimal only.***

```js
$(function(){
  //input number only.
  convertNumberFloatZero(22); // output : 22.00
  convertNumberFloatZero(22.5); // output : 22.50
  convertNumberFloatZero(22.55); // output : 22.55
  convertNumberFloatZero(22.556); // output : 22.56
  convertNumberFloatZero(22.555); // output : 22.55
  convertNumberFloatZero(22.5541); // output : 22.54
  convertNumberFloatZero(22222.5541); // output : 22,222.54

  function convertNumberFloatZero(number){
 if(!$.isNumeric(number)){
  return 'NaN';
 }
 var numberFloat = number.toFixed(3);
 var splitNumber = numberFloat.split(".");
 var cNumberFloat = number.toFixed(2);
 var cNsplitNumber = cNumberFloat.split(".");
 var lastChar = splitNumber[1].substr(splitNumber[1].length - 1);
 if(lastChar > 0 && lastChar < 5){
  cNsplitNumber[1]--;
 }
 return Number(splitNumber[0]).toLocaleString('en').concat('.').concat(cNsplitNumber[1]);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*Due to all told stuff. You may do 2 things for different purposes:
When showing/printing stuff use this in your alert/innerHtml= contents:
YourRebelNumber.toFixed(2)*/

var aNumber=9242.16;
var YourRebelNumber=aNumber-9000;
alert(YourRebelNumber);
alert(YourRebelNumber.toFixed(2));

/*and when comparing use:
Number(YourRebelNumber.toFixed(2))*/

if(YourRebelNumber==242.16)alert("Not Rounded");
if(Number(YourRebelNumber.toFixed(2))==242.16)alert("Rounded");

/*Number will behave as you want in that moment. After that, it'll return to its defiance.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple and works just as well as any of the others:

```
function parseNumber(val, decimalPlaces) {
    if (decimalPlaces == null) decimalPlaces = 0
    var ret = Number(val).toFixed(decimalPlaces)
    return Number(ret)
}
```

Since toFixed() can only be called on numbers, and unfortunately returns a string, this does all the parsing for you in both directions.  You can pass a string or a number, and you get a number back every time!  Calling parseNumber(1.49) will give you 1, and parseNumber(1.49,2) will give you 1.50.  Just like the best of 'em!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the  `.toPrecision()` method and some custom code, and always round up to the nth decimal digit regardless the length of int part.

```
function glbfrmt (number, decimals, seperator) {
    return typeof number !== 'number' ? number : number.toPrecision( number.toString().split(seperator)[0].length + decimals);
}
```

You could also make it a plugin for a better use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a TypeScript implementation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21323330/916734. It also dries things up with functions, and allows for a optional digit offset.

```js
export function round(rawValue: number | string, precision = 0, fractionDigitOffset = 0): number | string {
  const value = Number(rawValue);
  if (isNaN(value)) return rawValue;

  precision = Number(precision);
  if (precision % 1 !== 0) return NaN;

  let [ stringValue, exponent ] = scientificNotationToParts(value);

  let shiftExponent = exponentForPrecision(exponent, precision, Shift.Right);
  const enlargedValue = toScientificNotation(stringValue, shiftExponent);
  const roundedValue = Math.round(enlargedValue);

  [ stringValue, exponent ] = scientificNotationToParts(roundedValue);
  const precisionWithOffset = precision + fractionDigitOffset;
  shiftExponent = exponentForPrecision(exponent, precisionWithOffset, Shift.Left);

  return toScientificNotation(stringValue, shiftExponent);
}

enum Shift {
  Left = -1,
  Right = 1,
}

function scientificNotationToParts(value: number): Array<string> {
  const [ stringValue, exponent ] = value.toString().split('e');
  return [ stringValue, exponent ];
}

function exponentForPrecision(exponent: string, precision: number, shift: Shift): number {
  precision = shift * precision;
  return exponent ? (Number(exponent) + precision) : precision;
}

function toScientificNotation(value: string, exponent: number): number {
  return Number(`${value}e${exponent}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Any.twoDecimalPlaces(numInDouble: Double): String {

    return "%.2f".format(numInDouble)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I found a very simple way that solved this problem for me and can be used or adapted:

```
td[row].innerHTML = price.toPrecision(price.toFixed(decimals).length
```

Answer (score -5):

100% working!!! Try it

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <script>
      function replacePonto(){
        var input = document.getElementById('qtd');
        var ponto = input.value.split('.').length;
        var slash = input.value.split('-').length;
        if (ponto > 2)
                input.value=input.value.substr(0,(input.value.length)-1);

        if(slash > 2)
                input.value=input.value.substr(0,(input.value.length)-1);

        input.value=input.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/,'');

        if (ponto ==2)
 input.value=input.value.substr(0,(input.value.indexOf('.')+3));

if(input.value == '.')
 input.value = "";
              }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <input type="text" id="qtd" maxlength="10" style="width:140px" onkeyup="return replacePonto()">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline to answer.