# Is there a decimal math library for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, decimal, bigdecimal

Is there a mature library for doing decimal-based math, possibly arbitrary-precision, in JavaScript?

**Edit:** I want this information for a reference page on floating-point-related problems and alternatives to use when binary floating-point is inappropriate: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: 'The Server'. Seriously, wherefore do you need it? Serverside JS? Some special math? 3D on a canvas? ... That could perhaps help to search in the right direction.

Comment: Good question, but a duplicate. See:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287744/good-open-source-javascript-math-library-for-floating-point-operations

Comment: @Anthony that question is about **floating point**, while this question is (I think) about infinite-precision fixed-point. The second one you linked is clearly irrelevant.

Comment: There's another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library, but it is a year old. I'm curious on any updates.

Comment: @Boldewyn common use case: monetary manipulation for spreadsheet-like user interfaces

Comment: I was looking for such some time ago and I decided to write very simple class for my own (30 lines). I use integers + shifting for internal math so it has limited precision but for money calculations it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's been a "port" of the Java `BigDecimal` class (I think it's here: http://freshmeat.net/projects/js_bigdecimal/ ) for a long time. I looked at it a long time ago and it seemed kind-of cumbersome and huge, but (if that's the one I'm thinking of) it's been used as part of some cryptography tools so there's a decent chance that it works OK.

Because cryptography is a likely area to generate a need for such things, that's a good way to snoop around for such packages.

**edit:** Thanks @Daniel (comment to question) for this older SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library

Comment: The official homepage of the BigDecimal port seems to be this: http://stz-ida.de/html/oss/js_bigdecimal.html.en - I couldn't even find a way to download it from freshmeat.

Comment: Ah.  Well it shows up all over the place in google searches. It's been around for a long time.

Comment: The BigDecimal link is getting 404.  Seems the site was redesigned.  New link: http://stz-ida.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&Itemid=32

Comment: @spoulson, that new link gives a 404 also... :S

Answer (score 19):

As their author, I recommend [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) or [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js), 'a small, fast Javascript library for arbitrary-precision arithmetic with decimal numbers'.

For a more mature library, the [ICU4J BigDecimal](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) translation is also recommended.

Comment: The latter is actually the library mentioned in the other answer, now given a hopefully more permanent home on github.

Comment: bignumber.js is now on the [jsdelivr CDN](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!bignumber.js)

Answer (score 1):

Since it does not seem to be mentioned, here's [another one](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/). I haven't used it myself (yet), so I will update the post once I've given it a try.