# Math.pow() not giving precise answer

Tags: javascript, math, integer, user-defined-functions

I've used `Math.pow()` to calculate the exponential value in my project.

Now, For specific values like `Math.pow(3,40)`, it returns `12157665459056929000`.

But when i tried the same value using a scientific Calculator, it returns `12157665459056928801`.

Then i tried to traverse the loop till the exponential value :

```
  function calculateExpo(base,power){
    base = parseInt(base);
    power = parseInt(power);
    var output = 1;
    gameObj.OutPutString = '';  //base + '^' + power + ' = ';
    for(var i=0;i<power;i++){
      output *= base;
      gameObj.OutPutString += base + ' x ';
    }
    // to remove the last comma 
    gameObj.OutPutString = gameObj.OutPutString.substring(0,gameObj.OutPutString.lastIndexOf('x'));
    gameObj.OutPutString += ' =  ' + output;
    return output;
  }
```

This also returns `12157665459056929000`.
Is there any restriction to Int type in JS ?

Comment: Who is to define whether that `scientific calculator` is authentic or `math.pow`? Did you try any third method? If there is any limit, it is being applied to the result of scientific calculator, that is the lesser value

Comment: The scientific calculator is correct in this case.

Comment: @JosephMyers At least the number is odd which hints that it is more likely to be correct...

Comment: @JosephMyers how? can you back that up with an argument?

Comment: I recently read a blog post about this, but I cannot find it.  The closest thing I could find is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken .  Basically, I think it is because javascript uses 64 bit, and then eventually when the numbers get large enough it starts to give you the same number for every for 2 powers in a row before changing.

Comment: @Hanky : There is no authenticity to that calculator. but i compared my result with the calci because that was the only place i got a different answer. The calci I used was the one available with the windows-7

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is highly dependent on the platform you are running this code at. Interestingly even the browser matters even on the same very machine.

```
<script>
document.write(Math.pow(3,40));
</script>
```

On my 64-bit machine Here are the results:

**IE11**: `12157665459056928000`

**FF25**: `12157665459056929000`

**CH31**:  `12157665459056929000`

**SAFARI:** `12157665459056929000`

Comment: It's really odd that IE11 is 1000 off .. it *should* be consistent, I think.

Comment: You can try it for your machine and see if they are different?

Comment: I don't have IE11, but IE10/Win7/x64 reports "12157665459056928000" as well.

Comment: I've voted this up, because I think that it's curious that the pow function behaves differently - at least at the limits. I did not expect that behavior, even if I did expect losing bits of information.

Comment: `12157665459056928000 === 12157665459056929000` (IE11 just decided to convert it to a string differently, but they are both the same number. Unsurprising since they all probably use `pow` from the C runtime)

Answer (score 3):

52 bits of JavaScript's 64-bit double-precision number values are used to store the "fraction" part of a number (the main part of the calculations performed), while 11 bits are used to store the "exponent" (basically, the position of the decimal point), and the 64th bit is used for the sign. (Update: see this illustration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IEEE_754_Double_Floating_Point_Format.svg)

There are slightly more than 63 bits worth of significant figures in the base-two expansion of `3^40`  (63.3985... in a continuous sense, and 64 in a discrete sense), so hence it cannot be accurately computed using `Math.pow(3, 40)` in JavaScript. Only numbers with 52 or fewer significant figures in their base-two expansion (and a similar restriction on their order of magnitude fitting within 11 bits) have a chance to be represented accurately by a double-precision floating point value.

Take note that how large the number is does not matter as much as how many significant figures are used to represent it in base two. There are many numbers as large or larger than `3^40` which *can* be represented accurately by JavaScript's 64-bit double-precision number values.

Note:

`3^40 = 1010100010111000101101000101001000101001000111111110100000100001` (base two)

(The length of the largest substring beginning and ending with a 1 is the number of base-two significant figures, which in this case is the entire string of 64 digits.)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can only represent *distinct* integers [to 2<sup>53</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t?rq=1) (or ~16 significant digits). This is because *all* JavaScript numbers have an internal representation of [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) base-2 doubles.

As a consequence, the result from `Math.pow` (even if *was* accurate internally) is brutally "rounded" such that the result is still a JavaScript integer (as it is defined to return an integer per the specification) - and the resulting number is thus *not* the correct value, but the closest integer approximation of it JavaScript can handle.

I have put underscores above the digits that don't [entirely] make the "significant digit" cutoff so it can be see how this would affect the results.

```
................____
12157665459056928801     - correct value
12157665459056929000     - closest JavaScript integer
```

Another way to see this is to run the following (which results in true):

```
12157665459056928801 == 12157665459056929000
```

---

From the [The Number Type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.5) section in the specification:

> Note that all the positive and negative integers whose magnitude is no greater than 2<sup>53</sup> are representable in the Number type ..

.. but not all integers with large magnitudes are representable.

---

The only way to handle this situation in JavaScript (such that information is not lost) is to use an *external* number encoding and pow function. There are a few different options mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287744/good-open-source-javascript-math-library-for-floating-point-operations and [Is there a decimal math library for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622144/is-there-a-decimal-math-library-for-javascript)

For instance, with [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js), the code might look like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27E88/):

```
var z = new Big(3)
var r = z.pow(40)
var str = r.toString()
// str === "12157665459056928801"
```

Comment: Wow man how many edits? lol as soon as I start reading it says an edit has been made :D. Oh there you go again

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yeah, I need to go to EAA classes :(

Comment: Whats the solution then ? What do i do ?

Comment: @janakshah I've added one solution using big.js although there are other libraries available. Whatever is done, the result of pow(3, 40) *cannot* be a single JavaScript number.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell (ghci) gives

```
Prelude> 3^40
12157665459056928801
```

Erlang gives

```
1> io:format("~f~n", [math:pow(3,40)]).
12157665459056929000.000000
2> io:format("~p~n", [crypto:mod_exp(3,40,trunc(math:pow(10,21)))]).
12157665459056928801
```

JavaScript

```
> Math.pow(3,40)
  12157665459056929000
```

You get `12157665459056929000` because it uses IEEE floating point for computation. You get `12157665459056928801` because it uses arbitrary precision (bignum) for computation.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I know for sure, but this does look like a range problem.

I believe it is common for mathematics libraries to implement exponentiation using logarithms. This requires that both values are turned into floats and thus the result is also technically a float. This is most telling when I ask MySQL to do the same calculation:

```
> select pow(3, 40);
+-----------------------+
| pow(3, 40)            |
+-----------------------+
| 1.2157665459056929e19 |
+-----------------------+
```

It might be a courtesy that you are actually getting back a large integer.