# Javascript Prevent Automatic Rounding

Tags: javascript, rounding, precision, floating-point-precision, arbitrary-precision

I was wondering if there was any way to prevent javascript from automatically rounding my numbers. I made a program to calculate pi using the Gregory-Leibniz series. It only goes to a certain amount of decimal places. Here is my code:

```
pi=0;
x=1;
i=1;
function doStuff(){
    pi = pi+(4/x);
    x=x+2;
    pi = pi-(4/x);
    x=x+2;
    document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = pi;
}
```

Comment: It only goes to a certain number of decimal places because it only *has* a certain number of decimal places. JavaScript math has finite precision, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to work with numbers requiring precision beyond the JavaScript float (only 64 bits of precision) you could consider using a library like one of those mentioned in this question: [Is there a decimal math library for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622144/is-there-a-decimal-math-library-for-javascript)

In particular the [bignumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) library looks promising for your purposes.

Here is a quick demonstration jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H88tS/

Note that the fiddle is linking in the bignumber library.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    BigNumber.config({ DECIMAL_PLACES : 50, ERRORS : false});

    var pi = new BigNumber(0, 10),
        x = new BigNumber(1, 10),
        two = new BigNumber(2, 10),
        four = new BigNumber(4, 10);

    function iterate() {
        pi = pi.plus(four.dividedBy(x));
        x = x.plus(two);
        pi = pi.minus(four.dividedBy(x));
        x = x.plus(two);
        $("#pi").text(pi.toPrecision(50));
    }

    $('button').click(iterate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's computationally impossible to prevent rounding of a number with potentially infinite decimal places.

There are some hacks one could suggest, though, like having a class `HugeNumber` whose objects are lists or arrays of algarisms, or even strings that contain only numbers, and having arithmetic operations implemented in it (by yourself, of course). Unless processing efficiency is a concern, this would be an acceptable solution. Maybe something like that already exists in a plugin or even in some built-in class, I just never needed that so I really don't know.