# How do you represent number with decimals greater than or equal to 2^1024 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

A string representation works for integers >= 2^1024: see https://github.com/rauschma/strint.

However, I need these values to have more accuracy than integers. Additionally I need to handle multiplication, powers, and division of these large numbers. The final result will be be small enough to be a JavaScript number.

Comment: You're going to need to look for an infinite-precision fixed-point math package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to: [Is there a decimal math library for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622144/is-there-a-decimal-math-library-for-javascript)

There are a few libraries proposed in the answers there.

Comment: Thank you. This works for me.