# Fibonacci numbers 1 kk iteration

Tags: javascript, numbers, fibonacci, infinity, bignum

I've a function to calculate Fibonacci numbers

```
function fib(n) {
  var a = 1,
    b = 1;
  for (var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    var c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  return b;
}

alert( fib(3) ); // 2
alert( fib(7) ); // 13
alert( fib(77) ); // 5527939700884757
```

But with `n > 10000` I get `Infiniti` statement.

How can I calculate Fibonacci numbers over (`n > 1kk`) in JavaScript?

Comment: with a big number library it should be possible.

Comment: Yes, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622144/is-there-a-decimal-math-library-for-javascript) question's answer has some, and if you google for something like "javascript infinite precision arithmetic", there are a bunch of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a big-integer library. Either roll one yourself (it's not that complicated) or use on of the js-bigint libraries floating around on the net (Let me include a shameless [self-plug](https://github.com/czurnieden/Little/blob/master/libs/bignum.js) here).

But for lareg Fibonacci numbers you should use a different algorithm and do it by matrix exponetiation. If you use my bigint-library you can use the following script

```
function smallfibonacci(n) {
    var i = 1,
        j = 0,
        k, l;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        l = i + j;
        i = j;
        j = l;
    }
    return j;
}

function fibonacci(n) {
    var i = n - 1,
        r;
    var a, b, c, d, t, t1, t2, t3;
    var e;

    if (n <= 76) {
        return smallfibonacci(n).toBigint();
    }

    a = new Bigint(1);
    b = new Bigint(0);
    c = new Bigint(0);
    d = new Bigint(1);

    while (i > 0) {
        if (i & 0x1) {
            //t = d*(a + b) + c*b;
            t1 = c.mul(b);
            t2 = a.add(b);
            t3 = d.mul(t2);
            t = t3.add(t1);

            //a = d*b + c*a;
            t1 = d.mul(b);
            t2 = c.mul(a);
            a = t1.add(t2);
            //b = t;
            b = t.copy();
        }
        //t = d*(2*c + d);
        t1 = c.lShift(1);
        t2 = t1.add(d);
        t = d.mul(t2);

        //c = c*c + d*d;
        t1 = c.sqr();
        t2 = d.sqr();
        c = t1.add(t2);
        //d = t;
        d = t.copy();
        i >>>= 1;
    }
    r = a.add(b);
    return r;
}

fibonacci(10000).toString();
```

The conversion to string is still not optimized and needs most of the runtime here. Computing (but not printing!) F(1,000,000) needs about 24 seconds on this medium powered machine.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum integer in JavaScript is 2^53. The 1000th member of the Fibonacci sequence greatly exceeds this limit at ~4.35*10^208 so you'll need to use a big number library to compute numbers this high. Here's an example using [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) to easily solve this issue.

```
function fib(n) {
    var a = new Big(1),
        b = new Big(1);
    for (var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        var c = a.plus(b);
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}

alert(fib(3)); // 2
alert(fib(7)); // 13
alert(fib(77)); // 5527939700884757
alert(fib(1000)); // 4.346655768...e+208
```