# alternative to JSON.parse() for maintaining decimal precision?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm calling `JSON.parse()` to parse a JSON string which has small decimals.

The precision of the decimals is not being maintained after parsing.  For example, a value like `3.1e-7` is being returned instead of the actual decimal.

How can I deserialize a JSON string in ng2+ while maintaining decimal precision?

*UPDATE*

I was thinking about mapping out the values from the string and then setting the values manually to the object after JSON.parse() but when I set a different small decimal number as a property value, the same number formatting occurs.  So is this problem not necessarily unique to JSON.parse() but to Javascript in general?  Or does JSON.parse() somehow configure property types in a fixed way?

Comment: What is the actual decimal? What does the JSON object look like?

Comment: Please show your code.  `(var foo = JSON.parse('{"foo":0.000000315453}'); console.log(foo.foo)` ... gives "3.15453e-7", but this might be different depending on context

Comment: for example, 0.00000017 is returned as 1.7e-7

Comment: And `1.7e-7` is the actual representation of `0.00000017`

Comment: There's no loss of decimal precision there. I opened the console on Chrome and typed in `.00000000000214124214` and it returned `2.14124214e-12` which is the [exponential form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) of the number.

Comment: ok but is there maybe a formatting param that can be passed into JSON.parse() to keep the full decimal display representation?

Comment: Do you have any control over the original JSON object? `Number` is not the right type to store tiny numbers in.

Comment: or can you describe how I could display the full decimal in an ng2 view like {{ toFullDecimal(myExponentialNumber) }}

Comment: @aux - the json string is from a third party.  there is no Number type or any type specified in the json string and I'm guessing that JSON.parse() converts all decimals to numbers by default

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: @AuxTaco it's not the actual value that matters, but number of significant digits.

Answer (score 9):

As soon as you pass your JSON string through JSON.parse, you'll lose precision because of [the way floating point math works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?s=1|1083.3982). You'll need to store the number as an [object designed for storing arbitrary-precision numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622144/is-there-a-decimal-math-library-for-javascript), and you'll need to fiddle with the string itself before parsing it. The simplest way is with regexes. JSON is a context free grammar, and regexes work on regular grammars, so the warning applies:

> WARNING: PARSING CFG WITH REGEX [MAY SUMMON ZALGO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

This regex *should* turn the numbers in your JSON into strings:

```
let stringedJSON = origJSON.replace(/:\s*([-+Ee0-9.]+)/g, ': "uniqueprefix$1"');
```

But I haven't tested it extensively and it definitely will screw things up if you have keys that are something like `data:42`.

Assuming it worked correctly, `stringedJSON` should now be something like `{"foo": "uniqueprefix0.00000017", "bar": "an actual string"}`. You can parse this with `JSON.parse` without losing precision, but `uniqueprefix0.00000017` isn't what you want. `JSON.parse` can be called with an extra `reviver` argument, which transforms values passed to it before returning them. You can use this to convert your data back into a useful form:

```
let o = JSON.parse(stringedJSON, (key, value) => {
  // only changing strings
  if (typeof value !== 'string') return value;
  // only changing number strings
  if (!value.startsWith('uniqueprefix')) return value;
  // chop off the prefix
  value = value.slice('uniqueprefix'.length);
  // pick your favorite arbitrary-precision library
  return new Big(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that "summon Zalgo" link. Made my morning.

Comment: As you mentioned, that regex matches numbers in strings like "data:42". It also fails to match any numbers that are not object values (I.E. array values or a top-level standalone number). This regex will work for all numbers in any JSON and skip all numbers that are part of a string: `replace( /((?:[^"]*?(?:"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*?")?)*?)((?:[:,\[]|^)[\s\n]*)(-?(0|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d*)?)/gsy, '$1$2"uniqueprefix$3"')`