# jQuery limit to 2 decimal places

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

How do I limit the following jQuery return to 2 decimal places?

```
$("#diskamountUnit").val('$' + $("#disk").slider("value") * 1.60);
```

I figure I've got to throw toFixed(2) somewhere into there, but I can't seem to get the ordering right or something.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You could use a variable to make the calculation and use `toFixed` when you set the `#diskamountUnit` element value:

```
var amount = $("#disk").slider("value") * 1.60;
$("#diskamountUnit").val('$' + amount.toFixed(2));
```

You can also do that in one step, in the `val` method call but IMO the first way is more readable:

```
$("#diskamountUnit").val('$' + ($("#disk").slider("value") * 1.60).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: lol!... you both understood each other well... and here I am puzzled what's `toFixed()` was.... haha!

Comment: @Reigel: lol, [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is a method available for `Number` objects and values that returns a string containing the number represented in *fixed-point notation*, for example: `1.2345.toFixed(2); //--> "1.23"`, so the OP wants to display this formatted number to represent a currency amount `'$' + amount.toFixed(2)` --> `"$1.23"` ;)

Comment: cool!... I'm such a noob... my first real work in JS was with jQuery already... so there are more stuff I don't know about JS, that is not mostly use in jQuery... thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Here is a working example in both Javascript and jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/GuLYN/312/

```
//In jQuery
$("#calculate").click(function() {
    var num = parseFloat($("#textbox").val());
    var new_num = $("#textbox").val(num.toFixed(2));
});


// In javascript
document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = function() {
    var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById('textbox').value);
    var new_num = num.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('textbox').value = new_num;
};
​
```

Comment: thanks for the function `toFixed()` very useful and easy..