# I Want get a value by javascript sum value onclick function result is good but i want to fix value 2 dicimal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have need no large dicimal value only 2 need dicimal value so please help...

```
<script>
                $(function() {
                    $("#isum, #num1, #num2, #num3, #rec1, #rec2, #rec3, #difnum1, #difnum2, #difnum3").on("keydown keyup", sum);
                    function sum() {
                    $("#trec").val(Number($("#isum").val()) / Number($("#num2").val()));
                    $("#trec").val(Number($("#trec").val()) * Number($("#rec2").val()));    
                    //-----------------------------
                    $("#rec1").val(Number($("#num1").val()));
                    $("#difnum1").val(Number($("#rec1").val()));
                    //-----------------------------
                    $("#rec3").val(Number($("#num3").val()));
                    $("#difnum3").val(Number($("#rec3").val()));
                    //-----------------------------
                    $("#difnum2").val(Number($("#num2").val()) - Number($("#rec2").val()));
                    $("#tdifnum").val(Number($("#isum").val()) - Number($("#trec").val()));
                    }
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: use parseFloat(your  value ).tofixed(noOfDecimal) methods

Comment: Please edit my code dear and share me please

Comment: checkout new solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an existing numeric value, you can use the [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function to specify the number of significant digits that you want to include after the decimal point.

So in your case, you would just want to perform your calculations and add the `.toFixed(2)` following them:

```
// Example
$("#difnum2").val((Number($("#num2").val()) - Number($("#rec2").val())).toFixed(2));
```

For the sake of readability, you may want to consider parsing all of your values separately and performing your calculations using those:

```
$(function() {
    $("#isum, #num1, #num2, #num3, #rec1, #rec2, #rec3, #difnum1, #difnum2, #difnum3").on("keydown keyup", sum);
    function sum() {
        // Get your values
        var isum = Number($($"#issum").val()),
            num2 = Number($("#num2").val()),
            rec2 = Number($("#rec2").val()),
            num1 = Number($("#num1").val()),
            rec1 = Number($("#rec1").val()),
            num3 = Number($("#num3").val()),
            rec3 = Number($("#rec3").val());

        // Perform your calculations
        var trec = (isum / num2) * rec2,
            difnum2 = num2 - rec2,
            tdifnum = isum - trec;

        // Set your values
        $("#trec").val(trec);
        $("#rec1").val(num1);
        $("#difnum1").val(rec1);
        $("#rec3").val(num3);
        $("#difnum3").val(rec3);
        $("#difnum2").val(difnum2);
        $("#tdifnum").val(tdifnum);
    }
});
```

I'd also recommend considering some more meaningful names as to what each of these values are (and what is being calculated) as opposed to arbitrary names (e.g. num1, num2, rec1, rec2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You just add `toFixed` in the last of your decimal value.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var num = 1.122341345;
  var n = num.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the fixed number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

For your reference check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

As your code shows jquery, try this : [jQuery limit to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020273/jquery-limit-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

this way you can acheive:
 When you define a var, in JavaScript it is a string, so you need to parse.
According to @Rion Williams  stated , with number you can directly use toFixed() as it is just number which is going to convert in float value

```js
 (function() {
            $("#isum, #num1, #num2, #num3, #rec1, #rec2, #rec3, #difnum1, #difnum2, #difnum3").on("keydown keyup", sum);

            function sum() {
              $("#trec").val((Number($("#isum").val()) / Number($("#num2").val())).toFixed(2));
              $("#trec").val((Number($("#trec").val()) * Number($("#rec2").val())).toFixed(2));
              //-----------------------------
              $("#rec1").val((Number($("#num1").val())).toFixed(2));
              $("#difnum1").val((Number($("#rec1").val())).toFixed(2));
                //-----------------------------
                $("#rec3").val((Number($("#num3").val())).toFixed(2)); $("#difnum3").val((Number($("#rec3").val())).toFixed(2));
                //-----------------------------
                $("#difnum2").val((Number($("#num2").val()) - Number($("#rec2").val())).toFixed(2)); $("#tdifnum").val((Number($("#isum").val()) - Number($("#trec").val())).toFixed(2));
              }
            });
```

Comment: maim onclick function is not working after use edit code