# I want to validate a textbox which rounds to 2 places, using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to validate a textbox which rounds to two decimal places. However, I do **not** want to round up.

For example; if I enter 19.999 then the result will be 19.99, not 20.00

And if I enter 19.7, then result will be 19.70.  If I enter 19, then result will be 19.00

The toFixed() function is not working in my code.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function withPrec(number, digitsAfterComma) {
    if (digitsAfterComma <= 0 || digitsAfterComma > 10) return number; // bad args
    var str = String(number);
    var comma = str.indexOf('.');
    var zeroes = '0000000000'.substring(0, digitsAfterComma);
    return (comma == -1) ? 
        str + '.' + zeroes : (str + zeroes).substring(0, comma + digitsAfterComma + 1);
}
```

Using substring to avoid building an intermediate array.

Use as `withPrec(10.00001, 2)` or `withPrec(1, 5)`;

Comment: if I will enter 19.7 then it gives 19.7 but i want 19.70 in this case

Comment: Ah OK - yes, didn't think of that!

Comment: @Sanjeev, fixed that for you (it also failed to handle integers). Once it has more than a single line it is better to make a function for it.

Answer (score 0):

try working like,

```
parseInt(19.999 * 100)/100
```

for if you want to get `19.7` to `19.70` use following,

```
var num = parseInt(19.7 * 100).toString();
num = num.substring(0,num.length-2) +"."+ num.substring(num.length-2,num.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "19.99999";
var newString = string.split(string.indexOf('.') + 2)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better answer in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-rounding-to-two-decimal-places-not-less-than-two):
use Number(aNumber).[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)(2)