# Converting a value to 2 decimal places within jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Now that I have got a bit of script to add values in to a div with a total in it, I then try to divide the values by 100 to give me a decimal number (to make it look like currency).

After this the script works and gives me a nice decimal float, sometimes though a large recurring number comes after, I want to limit this to two decimals using the script i already have so was wondering if someone could implement something into my current script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
     $('#total').text(parseFloat($('#total').text()) + parseFloat($(this).data('amount'))/100);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to use the [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method

It takes as a parameter the number of digits to show after the decimal point.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
     var value = parseFloat($('#total').text()) + parseFloat($(this).data('amount'))/100
     $('#total').text( value.toFixed(2) );
  });
})
```

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 30):

Try to use this

```
parseFloat().toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Joni_demon    perfect way to get them. EX. 2344.989899  TO 2344.98

Comment: you are a life savor

Answer (score 10):

you can use just javascript for it

```
var total =10.8
(total).toFixed(2); 10.80


alert(total.toFixed(2)));
```

Comment: sorry, in terms of implementing that to my current code. How would i do that (new at coding)

Comment: look at the solution below it implements your code in it