# Textbox populated by jquery function needs decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

in a previous post, I received help with a jquery function that populates a textbox with a dropdown selection. I needed to use it to populate another textbox based on the same selection.

However, I need this textbox to have 2 decimal points and keep its value as a number because I will be using it in a calculation.  Here is the code that populates the textbox:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#RaffleDollars").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "25")
                $("#Total_Raffle").val(25);
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I get the value of `Total_Raffle` to display as 25.00 while keeping its format as a number used in a calculation?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881773/converting-a-value-to-2-decimal-places-within-jquery

Answer (score 1):

> while keeping its format as a number used in a calculation?

`input` element value is text , could convert to number object by casting with `Number(value)`

```
$("#RaffleDollars").change(function () {
 if ($(this).val() == "25")
   $("#Total_Raffle").val(25 + ".00");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
$('textbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var wDecimal = val.toFixed(2);
});
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for your answer. I know about .toFixed(2); but I guess I am not sure how to execute it in my code. I tried this but it did not work:

    $("#Total_Raffle").val(25).toFixed(2);

It still appeared in the textbox as 25. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `toFixed()` is applied to the value first. You need to run it before updating the value. `var amt = 25.toFixed(2); $('#Total_Raffle').val(amt);`