# How as a round number?

Tags: javascript

I need a round to two number after comma.
example

5000.0000 to 5000

5000.123 to 5000.12

5000.136 to 5000.13

how do this?

I need function x.toFixed(2); but if at the end of two zero, then they should not show

Comment: I think you want to round after "dot" you specified after comma"

Comment: @MiqdadAli: Not all countries use a decimal dot. For example, in Germany  we use `123.456.789,12345` (actually, the official way is `123 456 789,12345` but most people use dots anyway - but the decimal point is always the comma)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: **[JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)**

Comment: @ThiefMaster, true enough, but he did use periods/dots in his question.

Comment: @freakish you should seriously put that as an answer :s

Comment: @SiGanteng I could, but then again OP should google for it in the first place. It is common knowledge after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript function to round the number

```
function roundNumber(rnum, rlength) { 
  var newnumber = Math.round(rnum*Math.pow(10,rlength))/Math.pow(10,rlength);
return parseFloat(newnumber);
}

var num = roundNumber(5000.0000,0);   //will return 5000
```

Comment: roundNumber(5000.0000,2);  // will return 5000.00

Answer (score 0):

As @freakish suggests, `toFixed` is good idea to round numbers. If you want to floor it, I suggest

```
parseInt(5000.136*100)/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `x.toFixed(2)` returns a string you may do something like this:

```
function cut(str) {
    if (str[str.length-1] == "0")
        return str.substr(0, str.length-1);
    if (str[str.length-1] == ".")
        return str.substr(0, str.length-1);
    return str;
}

x = cut(cut(cut(x.toFixed(2))));
```

Not the most elegant (for example you could add the function to string's prototype), but definetly working.

Answer (score -1):

This link can help you

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Example

Convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals:

> var num = 5.56789; var n=num.toFixed(2);

The result of n will be:

> 5.57