# Formatting numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Can some one please help me with my java script?
My java script consistently counts up, the problem is the cents character length is way too long (need 2 characters max). Another problem is, I don't know what code additionally I need to put commas in the correct position for determining the proper amount. Example: 12345.67 vs 12,345.67. If some one can just take a look at the code, modify it and re-post the full code since I have no idea what to do, I would deeply appreciate it.

This is the javascript code: http://jsfiddle.net/pqsH6/

---

```
<p style="float:left;">Money Saved: </p><b><p id="ds"  style="float:left;">$</p></b>
<div id="counter" style="float:left;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var START_DATE = new Date("january 1, 2012 12:00:00"); // put in the starting date here   
    var INTERVAL = 1000; // savings per second
    var INCREMENT = 0.005; // money saved per second
    var START_VALUE = -50000; // configures proper savings calculation
    var count = 0;
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1;
        var now = new Date();
        count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
        setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
    }
</script>​
```

Comment: JavaScript numbers are **floating point** and are therefore seriously ill-suited to monetary calculations.

Comment: There's a javascript function called [ToFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) that will do what you are looking for.

Comment: You just asked this question (and then subsequently deleted it). The answer was posted in the comments of that question.

Comment: yea your right, but i am not experienced with java script and expected some one who is to take a little time out of there day to help me get this working, i stated i do not know where it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a way to format your output with commas using Javascript:

[How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Just pass your numbers through  the function as a parameter and it will return a comma delimited number.

Here's another function you can use to round out to two decimal places:

```
function formatCurrency(num) {
    num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num;
    return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
}
```

Then use the function like this

```
var roundedCurrencyAmt = numberWithCommas(formatCurrency(amtOfMoney));
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexfromapex/Y2x8m/2/

Comment: im sorry i can not seem to get it to work, im sure i am doing it wrong =/

Comment: i guess this problem will not get resolved, i dont know what to do with the code you sent me, i just asked for a small favor to repost the full code but i guess every one has no time for me =/

Comment: @Zach Here is the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexfromapex/Y2x8m/2/

Comment: OMG Alex (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1399491/alex-w), thank you so much, thankfully some one took a few seconds our of there day to help us.

Comment: It may be better to remove any existing commas before inserting more: `x.toString().replace(/,/g,'').replace(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:

```
> var START_DATE = new Date("january 1, 2012 12:00:00");
```

Relies on the built–in Date function parsing the string correctly, but ECMA-262 specifies only [one format](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15) (a version of ISO8601) that Date should parse and that isn't it. But not all browsers in use support that format.

Better to use something that is both [specified](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.2) and known to work everywhere, e.g.:

```
var START_DATE = new Date(2012,0,1,12);
```

which will create a new date of 2012-01-01 12:00:00 in the local timezone in all browsers, or if [UTC](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.3) is required then:

```
var START_DATE = new Date(Date.UTC(2012,0,1,12));
```