# Total Price variable limit to 2 decimals using ajax with php

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the following code snippet to calculate a total price.  This works great except #totalPrice on some occasions expands out to for example $267.9999999999.  How do I reformat #totalPrice within this function to just round to two decimals as is standard in dealing with price.

```
function getTotalCost(inventory) {
    if(inventory) {
        getTotalParts(inventory);
        getTotalMarkup(inventory);
    }

    var labor = $('#labor').val() * 1;
    var totals = 0;
    for(i in totalMarkup) {
        totals += totalMarkup[i];
    }
    totalCost = totals+labor;
    /*if(totals == 0) {
        totalCost = 0;
    }*/
    $('#totalPrice').html(totalCost);
}
```

Comment: duplicate answered here i believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals

Comment: `$('#labor').val() * 1` what a strange way, for casting to `Number` ??!!!

Comment: i actually like it :) if the value is not a number you'll get NaN

Comment: @fmsf You could get the same with `+$('#labor').val()` either.

Comment: @Engineer that could make a concat on other scopes while *1 will always convert it to a number

Comment: @fmsf Can you show an example of such scope?

Comment: x = "123"; x + 1 == "1231"; while x*1 + 1 = 124

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13383/discussion-between-fmsf-and-engineer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have:

```
$('#totalPrice').html(totalCost.toFixed(2));
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Notice that `toFixed` method returns a formatted number, therefore converts the number to a string. It's not a problem here because `html` wants a string, but it's keep it in mind that in order to avoid concatenation of string when you expects sum of numbers. I believe you use `$('#labor').val() * 1;` for this very reason. However it's not necessary, it's better use method like [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29):

```
var labor = +$('#labor').val();
```

Comment: excellent, thanks for the help.  Just so I know why is it better to use parseFloat or unary?

Comment: It depends from what is the input you have. I usually prefer the unary plus because it's an operator therefore is not a function call. But sometimes `parseFloat` does a better job if I want actually "parse" (as the method said) the input string and not just convert. Ti give some concrete example, if you have `+"31.40 USD"` you will get `NaN`. Instead, with `parseFloat("31.40 USD")` you will have `31.4` as number. See the link I gave in my answer for further details

Answer (score 1):

When working with javascript the floating points are always a bad. Best you can do is, round it up.

But in this case you can do

```
(totalCost).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.round function in JavaScript like this.

```
totalCost = Math.round(totalCost*100)/100;
$('#totalPrice').html(totalCost);
```