# converting integer to float with precision 2 using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the integer to floating number with precision 2. ie. -

11  =>  11.00

45  =>  45.00

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Comment: you have to explain more, if you want the conversion for display purposes, 11 + ".00" will do. If you convert interger to float, the decimal places are always 0

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var num = 45;
num.toFixed(2); //"45.00"
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that the return value will be a `string` and not a `float`

Answer (score 4):

```
var num = 10;
var result = num.toFixed(2);
```

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html

Answer (score 3):

This a very common problem
I see someone has already answered, I want to add to it,
if you want to further use the number after conversion for calculations
Try this in console

```js
a = 10.2222;
console.log(typeof a) // "number"
console.log(a)        // 10.2222 

b = parseFloat(a).toFixed(2);
console.log(typeof b) // "String"
console.log(b)        // "10.22"

c = parseFloat(b)
console.log(typeof c) // "number"
console.log(c)        // 10.22
```

Explanation is-

```
toFixed() method outputs a string variable
but if you want to further use the value of b as a 'number'
you will have to, 
c = parseFloat(b)
typeof c
// "number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `toFixed(2)` here with your variable.