# round 2 decimals syntax from from input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple conversion form from kg to lbs.

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="kg" name="kg">
<input type="text" id="lbs" name="lbs">
```

I have it setup so that the lbs box updates while you type in the kg box with this code.

**jQuery**

```
$("#kg").keyup(function(){
    $('#lbs').val($('#kg').val()*2.20462);
});
```

How do I get the lbs value to round to 2 decimals places? I am sure it is something fairly simple but all the examples I found online are for if the number is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
$('#lbs').val(($('#kg').val()*2.20462).toFixed(2));
```

---

```
number.toFixed( [digits] )
```

> **Parameter**
>
> **digits** The number of digits to appear after the decimal point; this
> may be a value between 0 and 20, inclusive, and implementations may
> optionally support a larger range of values. If this argument is
> omitted, it is treated as 0.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A string representation of number that does not use exponential
> notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The
> number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with
> zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length. If number is
> greater than 1e+21, this method simply calls Number.toString() and
> returns a string in exponential notation.

Comment: Wow I was SO close! I was trying this `$('#lbs').val($('#kg').val()*2.20462).toFixed(2);` Thank you so much! I will accept your awnser when it lets me in 10 minutes.

Comment: @user1738750, yes, your's has an error with the braces, but you were close indeed. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
var string = yourNumber.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: @ZoltanToth To be fair... there is probably a jQuery plugin for that (I know I made a js lib for more advanced number formatting)

Answer (score 1):

also this

```
(10.8).toFixed(2); // 10.80

var num = 2.4;
alert(num.toFixed(2)); // 2.40
```

[Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)