# how to round summ of two inputs with jquery

Tags: jquery, function, rounding

I have this function:

```
function doCalc() {
  var total = 0;
  $('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find('span.amount').html($('input:eq(0)', this).val() * $('input:eq(1)', this).val());
  });    
} 

$(this).keyup(doCalc);
```

and for example if I multiply    12 * 1.90 it always shows 22.799999999999997   How to format it to 22.80 ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n=num.toFixed(2);
```

The result of n will be:
5.57

Comment: I tried this and it is working but where to apply toFixed(2); in my code? sorry for being ... :)

Comment: Try this
$(this).find('span.amount').html(($('input:eq(0)', this).val() * $('input:eq(1)', this).val()).toFixed(2));

Comment: You should add toFixed(2) also to first input. Otherwise if first number will be for example 7.9, you again have same problem. So answer to @user1820186 is to add toFixed(2) to all input values. ps. I see no one accepted.

Comment: I have added toFixed() to the product of two inputs so there is no need to add it separately to individual inputs.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `toFixed`

```
var test = 10.231;
alert(test.tofixed(test))

returns 10.23
```

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply the result by 100 and then divide by 100.

or you can also use result.toFixed(2);