# 3 decimal places in javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal-point

I'm new to programming and I am starting with javascritpt, I have this code and I want the printed values to be to 3 decimal places.

```
<script>
for (var a = 3, b = 2; b >= 0; a ++, b --) {
document.writeln (a + " / " + b + " = " + a/b + "<br />")
}
</script>
```

I tried:

```
var a=a.toFixed(3);
var b=b.toFixed(3);
```

but it doesn't make a difference. The fist line comes out as 4 / 3 = 1.3333333333333333 instead of 1.333 which is what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
document.writeln (a + " / " + b + " = " + (a/b).toFixed(3) + "<br />")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toFixed(3)` at the time you divide. Like `(a/b).toFixed(3)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
for (var a = 3, b = 2; b >= 0; a ++, b --) {
    var c = (a/b).toFixed(3);
    document.writeln (a + " / " + b + " = " + c + "<br />")
}
</script>
```