# Replace 56666.666666666664% percentage in to three digit percentage using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have calculated some data usign javascript and result is printing like this (56666.666666666664%). and I need to convert the result in like 56.66%. Below is a Javascript which print the above result.

```
$scope.totaTaken = (totalT / data.length)*100;
```

Comment: sory but 56666 isn't the same as 56.

Comment: The answer is `.toFixed()`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals

Comment: Are you sure you dont mean to have (data.length/totalT) instead of what you have now? Becasue changing 56666 to 56 is just wrong and you should not do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a JavaScript solution (where you do it in a controller or directive), the given comments answer your question (see [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)). If you're looking for an AngularJS solution, where you format the value in the view, check out the [`number` filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3anumber) which was made for this!