# javascript mortgage calculator function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I got this almost working but for some reason have a remainder on the amortization chart.  I think it may be an issue with rounding but am not sure.  If anyone has experience with this can you take a look at the monthly payment function.  This is part of a small backbone.js app I was developing and you can see it in action http://rvb.chrismills.la

```
// Calculate mortgage based on selected values
calculateRBV: function() {
     var _this = this;
    // Make sure the correct downpayment is displaying
    _this.calculateDP();
    var _calcRent = $('#rvbRent').val();
    var _calcVal = $('#rvbBuy').val();
    var _calcDpPercent = $('#rvbDP').val()/100;
    var _calcDpAmt = _calcVal * _calcDpPercent;
    var _calcFinanced = _calcVal - _calcDpAmt;
    var _calcLength = $('#rvbTerm').val() * 12;
    var _calcRate = $('#rvbRate').val()/100/12;
    var _calcTaxes = $('#rvbTaxes').val();
    var _calcHpChange = $('#rvRentChangeVal').val();
    var _calcRentChange = $('#rvRentChangeVal').val();
    var _monthlyPayment = Math.floor((_calcFinanced*_calcRate)/(1-Math.pow(1+_calcRate,(-1*_calcLength)))*100)/100;
    var _totalPayments = _monthlyPayment * _calcLength;
    var _totalInterest = _totalPayments - _calcVal;
    var _totalRent = _calcRent * _calcLength;
    $('#rvbMonthly span').html(_this.formatNumber(_monthlyPayment));
    $('#rvbTotal span').html(_this.formatNumber(_totalPayments));
    $('#rvbInterest span').html(_this.formatNumber(_totalInterest));
    _this.buildAmortizationChart(_calcFinanced, _monthlyPayment, _calcLength, _calcRate);
    $('#rvbGraph').stop().slideDown(250);
    $('#amortizationChart').stop().slideDown(250);
},

// Build Amortization Chart
buildAmortizationChart: function(total, monthlyPayment, months, rate) {
    var _this = this;
    $('#amortizationChart tbody').html(''); // clear previous
    var _total = total;
    var _monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment;
    var _months = months;
    var _rate = rate;
    for(var i=1; i<=months; i++) {
        var _interest = _total * _rate;
        var _principal = _monthlyPayment - _interest;
        _total = _total - _principal;
var aRow = '';
aRow += '<tr>';
aRow += '<td width="20%">';
aRow += i;
aRow += '</td>';
aRow += '<td width="20%">';
aRow += '$' + _monthlyPayment;
aRow += '</td>';
aRow += '<td width="20%">';
aRow += '$' + _this.formatNumber(_principal);
aRow += '</td>';
aRow += '<td width="20%">';
aRow += '$' + _this.formatNumber(_interest);
aRow += '</td>';
aRow += '<td width="20%">';
aRow += '$' + _this.formatNumber(_total);
aRow += '</td>';
aRow += '</tr>';
$('#amortizationChart tbody').append(aRow);
}
},
```

Comment: create a live demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Could you indicate more exactly which variable has the extra remainder?

Comment: or you can just click the link so I don't have to compile all the js files into a js fiddle.

Comment: looks like the total in the amortization chart has the remainder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can see that on line 133 in index.js `_total` is indeed not an integer:

```
_total = _total - _principal;
```

If you want to get an integer, you can just do this:

```
_total = Math.round(_total - _principal);
```

Or, if you want to get a specific number of decimals, see this post: [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Is this what you meant by remainder?