# Javascript to show price with 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that has 5 fields for a user to put how much they want to pay for 5 separate items.  I then have it automatically totaling it at the bottom.  Since this total goes to a payment gateway I need to force it to round to 2 decimal places.

Can someone tell me how to change the code to do this?  I am a newbie with this.

Here is the code I have:

```
<script>
    function calculatepay(pay) {
var one = document.getElementById(pay + 'Student1Total').value;
var two = document.getElementById(pay + 'Student2Total').value;
var three = document.getElementById(pay + 'Student3Total').value;
var four = document.getElementById(pay + 'Student4Total').value;
var five = document.getElementById(pay + 'Student5Total').value;

var payTotal = document.getElementById(pay + 'payTotal');
payTotal.value = Number(one) + Number(two) + Number(three) + Number(four) + Number(five) ;
    calculateTotal();
}


</script>


<input type="text" id="pay1Student1Total" name="data1" onKeyUp="calculatepay('pay1');" /><br />
<input type="text" id="pay1Student2Total" name="data2" onKeyUp="calculatepay('pay1');" /><br />
<input type="text" id="pay1Student3Total" name="data3" onKeyUp="calculatepay('pay1');" /><br />
<input type="text" id="pay1Student4Total" name="data4" onKeyUp="calculatepay('pay1');" /><br />
<input type="text" id="pay1Student5Total" name="data5" onKeyUp="calculatepay('pay1');" /><br /><br /><br />
Total: 
<input type="text" id="pay1payTotal" onKeyUp="calculateTotal();" value="0"/><br /><br />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Comment: Did my answer do what you were looking for? If so, could you please toggle the check button next to it? It won't hurt, promise!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the toFixed(2) function in JavaScript to convert numbers to a fixed value.

It's used like this:

```
payTotal.value.toFixed(2)
```

So if the input value is 1, it'll look like 1.00

Comment: When I made this change to the code it did not work.  I think I may have added to the wrong location.  Where in the code do I add this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use .toFixed() method :

```
var x = 5.1232;
console.log(x.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this : `toFixed(2);` It will round to two decimal places

Answer (score 0):

var x = 5.1232;
console.log(Number(x.toFixed(2)));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Math.round(num * 100) / 100`

Comment: Not sure how to use this method either.  I tried to add this also and it did not work.  Where in the code do I add this?  Thanks.