# how to display decimal for input text taken from db onload in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to `display decimal` for input text taken from a database, onload in JavaScript.

Am having value as `100` when displaying it from the database into a text box. It should be `100.00`. Is it possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Comment: but am getting the value from session so that only it is not known how to specify value="<?php echo empty($this->session->store['actual_spending']['actual_total_private_funding']) ? '' : $this->session->store['actual_spending']['actual_total_private_funding'];

Comment: why do you use javascript for that...if your values come from db then you can display using php

Comment: how to give it in the above code?

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript**

```
function onclick(id)
{
  document.getElementById('text').value = id.toFixed(2);
}
```

you can set `100` as `100.00` using **php**

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo number_format($row['numbert'],'2','.',''); ?>" />
```

Comment: hi prafulla am getting into one variable  $('#actual_total_public_funding').val(addCommas(item.total_public_funding)); here am adding commas can i add decimal here along with comma?

Comment: @user2419839 I gt your question about comma and decimal and answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to toFixed javascript function:

```
var x = 100;
document.getElementById('textbox').value = x.toFixed(2);
```