# In javascript, how do I display "0" at the end of "$1.3" only when it's a whole number, not like "$1.32"?

Tags: javascript

What I'm doing is getting user input with

```
var x = document.getElementById('id');
```

and the output is in whole numbers due to rounding errors, so 1.34 is 134 and I display it with

```
id.innerHTML = '$'.concat(amount / 100);
```

It is displaying "$1.32" correctly but I don't want "$1.3" for consistencies sake. 
So my question is what would be the best way for detecting that "$2.6" for example needs a "0" at the end whereas "$2.53 doesn't? And how to I implement that?

Comment: did you see this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: [MDN: Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places 

parseFloat(Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
id.innerHTML = '$'.concat((amount / 100).toFixed(2));
```

It will convert a number to a string with the number of decimal places specified.

Comment: @FelixKling Well, I would say because it never hurts to try, but I see your point about a little more explanation being helpful. I edited the post to add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks that did it! I kept trying (amount.toFixed(2) / 100) but I see how that makes a lot more sense. I'm really new to javascript so the other threads weren't making sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.toFixed(2)` at the end of the number that you want to format

Answer (score 1):

Use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString`:

```
function formatUSD(value) {
    return value.toLocaleString(['en-US'], {
        style: 'currency', 
        currency: 'USD', 
        minimumFractionDigits: 2, 
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
    });
}
id.textContent = formatUSD(amount / 100);
```

You probably also want to use a library like [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) instead of floating-point numbers.

Comment: @sehe ECMAScript 3rd Edition. Implemented in JavaScript 1.5.

Comment: Note that not all browsers (versions) support the parameters that `toLocaleString` accepts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

[Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

use

```
.toFixed(number of decimal);
```