# JS - Format number with 2 decimal not rounded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would format a number with 2 decimal places without rounding.
So I excluded the toFixed() function.

I have tried this way

```
a = 1,809999
b = 27,94989

a = Math.floor(a * 100) / 100; --> 1,8
b = Math.floor(b * 100) / 100; --> 27,94

OR

a = Number(a.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)); --> 1,8
b = Number(b.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)); --> 27,94
```

Unfortunately, the second decimal of a is zero, and this was deleted, how could I do to keep it and have a = 1.80?
Thank you

Comment: You're confusing rounding with formatting.

Comment: try using this: a.toFixed(2) // this fixes to two decimal places

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: formatting number with exactly two decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(Math.floor(a * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

With toFixed(2) !

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkjgm045/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
a= a.toString().slice(0, (a.indexOf("."))+3);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkjgm045/1/)**

Comment: You forgot second `a` is number in yours oneliner. Solution `a = a.toString(); a.slice(0, (a.indexOf("."))+3); ` or `a = a.toString().slice(0, (a.toString().indexOf("."))+3); `

Answer (score 0):

Rounding a number is about changing it's value, and should be done with math operations (Math.floor, Math.ceil, Math.round, ...).

Formatting number, is about how do numbers get displayed to a human user (like Date formatting).

Javascript does not comes with acceptable native tool to do number formatting.

You can always play with rounding to make javascript print a number the way you want, but you will end up writing a lot of (possibly buggy) code.

I would recommend using a library to format your numbers
http://numeraljs.com/

```
numeral(number).format('0.00');
```

Answer (score 0):

only need to use toFixed() and pass number like 2 then it show after . two decimal like bello

```
a = 1,809999
b = 27,94989

a = Math.floor(a * 100) / 100; 
b = Math.floor(b * 100) / 100; 

$(".testa").text(a.toFixed(2)); //see here.
$(".testb").text(b.toFixed(2)); //see here.
```

Html :

```
<div class="testa"></div>
<br>
    <div class="testb"></div>
```

i hope this will help you. and also see this jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/RGerb/394/

Answer (score 0):

```
myFunction(value: number){
let x = value + ''; 
  var a =  x.lastIndexOf('.')>=0?parseFloat(x.substr(0,x.lastIndexOf('.')+(3))):value;
  var am = a.toFixed(2)
  console.log("Output: " + am);
  return am;
```

}

```
<button (click)="myFunction(656565.9668985)">My Function</button>

Output: 656565.96
```