# How to keep .00 in using checkbox calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I enabled/disabled the checkbox button, the added .00 removed from the amount.

How can I add the .00 to the amount?

Below is my code:

```
function checks() {
    document.getElementById('other_donation_check').checked = false;
}

function add(total, this_chk_bx) {
    var thetotal = form2.thetotal.value;

    if (this_chk_bx.checked == true) {
        //add if its checked
        var count=0;
        form2.thetotal.value = Number(thetotal) + Number(total);
        count++;
    } else {
        //subtract if its unchecked
        form2.thetotal.value = thetotal - total;
    }
}
```

and I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twince/fmxc6so7/5/).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Number.toFixed(2) to fixed turns it into a string with n decimals

Comment: [**`.toFixed()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: i tried .toFixed(2) method but i didnt get. can you please check my code "var thetotal = form2.Number(thetotal).value.toFixed(2);"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS - Format number with 2 decimal not rounded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941224/js-format-number-with-2-decimal-not-rounded)

Comment: sorry i tried like this but didnt work.

Comment: `.toFixed()` should definitely work @Twinxz. Take a close look at your attempt and the possible error you got.

Comment: @ nyedidikeke.  var thetotal = form2.thetotal.value; how can i add .toFixed() function above code.

Comment: ^ `parseFloat(form2.thetotal.value, 10).toFixed(2)` ? You have nested object there, make sure each value is correct first.

Comment: @Chay22,
 
var thetotal = parseFloat(form2.thetotal.value, 10).toFixed(2); alert(thetotal); alert value shows .00 but textbox value didn't show .00

Comment: @Twinxz: check my answer below; `.toFixed()` works and can help you achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Find below a snippet using `toFixed()` to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve; you can expand on that with your actual logics.

```js
(function add() {
  document.getElementById('other_donation_check').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var this_chk_bx = document.getElementById('other_donation_check').checked;
    var amount_one = 2,
      amount_two = 250;
    if (this_chk_bx === true) {
      console.log('is checked');
      var thetotal = eval(amount_two + amount_one);
      console.log(thetotal.toFixed(2));
    } else {
      console.log('is not checked');
      var thetotal = eval(amount_two + amount_one);
      console.log(thetotal);
    }
  });
}());
```

```html
<p>Check / uncheck the checkbox below to see the code in action.</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="other_donation_check">
```