# jquery suffix .00 for whole number

Tags: jquery, formatting, numbers

In jquery, I use the statement

`$("#amtReqTxt").val(parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2));`

When amount = 12, `textbox` shows 12. But I want to show the value as 12.00 in `textbox`. How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1726630/448591

Comment: It should work, works in Chrome