# Rounding Numbers to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, rounding

This is my first JS script. It's a currency calculator and I have a problem with it.

The code produces the value of the new currency after the user inserts the amount, the exchange rate and the currency. However, it gives a return like this

8.100000000000001.

I have been reading about Number.toFixed(x) and Number.toPrecision(x) but I have no idea where to put them in my code, or even if this is the best way to do it.

Please would somebody advise me, code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Currency Converter</title>
<script>
//Gets Values from TextBox
var number1, exchangeRate, result;
function setValues() {
    number1 = Number(document.getElementById("number1").value);
    exchangeRate = Number(document.getElementById("exchange-rate").value);

}

//Calculates Values from TextBox
function calculate() {
    setValues();
    result = number1*exchangeRate;  
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = result;
}

 //Prints the selected currency
function printCurrency() {
var myCurrency = document.getElementById("myCurrency").value;
    document.getElementById("print-currency").innerHTML = myCurrency;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Insert Amount <input type="text" id="number1">
    </td>

    <td>
        Exhange Rate <input type="text" id="exchange-rate">
    </td>

    <td>
        Select currency 
        <select id="myCurrency">
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="GPB">GBP</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            <option value="VND">VMD</option>
            <option value="KHR">KHR</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td>
    <input type="button" onclick="printCurrency(); calculate()" value="Calculate">
    </td>

</tr>

</table>



<p>Your amount is: <span id="print-currency"></span> <span id="answer"</span></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/javascript-formatting-number-with-exactly-two-decimals

Answer (score 3):

Apply it to your result.

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = result.toFixed(2);
```

---

In JS you can apply these functions to any number.

```
var a = 8.100000000000001;
console.log(a.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I didn't know where I could add the toFixed part. Now I do! :)

Comment: Please follow this tutorial: **www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp**

Answer (score 0):

Modify function calculate as :

> function calculate() {
>
> ```
> setValues();
> result = number1*exchangeRate;  
> document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = result.toFixed(2);
> ```
>
> }