# Round 2 decimals float number jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to round a float up to 2 decimals.

I've 3 pars

```
a = 0.83;
b = 44.5;
c = a * b
```

(result on calculator is "36.935". result on source code is "36.934999999999995");

I will need to be rounded up so I end up with the following:

```
36.94
```

When I use the following method:

```
Math.round(c * 100) / 100;
```

The result is:

```
36.93
```

Anybody can help me to round it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing `Math.round` `36.934999999999995`, it's always going to be `36.93`.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var a = 0.83;
var b = 44.5;
var c = a*b;
console.log(Math.round(c.toFixed(3) * 100) / 100);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickly answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question

```
function precise_round(num, decimals) {
    var t=Math.pow(10, decimals);   
    return (Math.round((num * t) + (decimals>0?1:0)*(Math.sign(num) * (10 / Math.pow(100, decimals)))) / t).toFixed(decimals);
}
```

Thank you Miguel for his answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14839776/5118223