# Jquery Round to 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to round this value "1153.7759999999999" to 1153.78 dynamically

Comment: `Number("1153.7759999999999").toFixed(2)`

Comment: `var num = parseInt("1153.7759999999999");
var n = num.toFixed(2); `

Comment: note that using .toFixed() will yield a string of the nominated length - you will need to reparse it as a number if you want to do calculations on it after rounding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var num =1153.7759999999999;
var result=Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `.toFixed(2)`

```
var num = 1153.7759999999999;
console.log(num.toFixed(2));
```