# Javascript rounding to the desired number of decimal places issue

Tags: javascript, rounding

I use a function which rounds to the desired number of decimal places:

```
function modRound(value, precision)
{
    var precision_number = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.round(value * precision_number) / precision_number;
}
```

It works correct, but not with 0.565. `modRound(0.575, 2)` gives 0.58 (correct), but `modRound(0.565, 2)` gives 0.56; I expect 0.57:

```js
function modRound(value, precision) {
  var precision_number = Math.pow(10, precision);
  return Math.round(value * precision_number) / precision_number;
}
function test(num) {
  console.log(num, "=>", modRound(num, 2));
}
test(0.575);
test(0.565);
```

Why is this happening and what to do?

Comment: `.565 * 100` results in `56.49999999999999` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @JEY No, a `.5` will be rounded UP `Math.round(56.5) // -> 57`

Comment: @vlaz you are right! my mistake

Comment: Actually, `modRound(0.575, 2)` also exhibits this behavior, because `0.575 * 100` is `57.49999999999999`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, `.585` would work as expected. Is it worth changing the example in the OP?

Comment: @vlaz: Thought I'd leave that to Alexey.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair point, I wasn't sure if it'd be good practice to do that.

Comment: @vlaz: Six years later, neither am I. :-)

Comment: Alexey - See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript/21323330#21323330).

Comment: T.J. Crowder, thanks! It's exactly what i need!

Answer (score -1):

You can add a very small number like this:

```
function modRound(value, precision)
{
    var precision_number = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.round((value+0.00000000001) * precision_number) / precision_number;
}
alert(modRound(0.565, 2))
```

here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4avtj7jj/)

Comment: This is just bad. This breaks other test cases, rather than fixing the root issue.