# How to add code for allow only two digits after decimal in my code

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jquery. I have form with two text boxes. In that i am restrict special characters.

Now i want implement decimal values for only two digits.

```
<form>
 <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="minAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Min.Amount</label>
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="minAmt" name="minAmt" placeholder="Enter Min Amount"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="maxAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Max.Amount</label>
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxAmt" name="maxAmt" placeholder="Enter Max Amount"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Script code here:

```
<script>
$('#minAmt').keyup(function(){
var reg = /^0+/gi;
if (this.value.match(reg)) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(reg, '');
}
if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]./g)) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
}
});
$('#maxAmt').keyup(function(){
var reg = /^0+/gi;
if (this.value.match(reg)) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(reg, '');
}
if (this.value.match(/[^0-9.]/g)) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
}
});
```

How to implement logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Comment: give some sample values that may help us to understand yours requirement

Comment: @R.Anandan: `10.05` or `100.50` etc.....

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#textbox').on('blur',function(){
    var num = parseFloat($("#textbox").val());
    var new_num = $("#textbox").val(num.toFixed(2));
    
    alert('Only two desimal number shold be acceptable..');return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="textbox" value="1.1251112314555" />
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GuLYN/312/) is another demo for on click event. hope this help you!

Comment: it's not related me. System doesn't allow 3rd digit

Comment: @Durga, You have mention **"allow only two digits after decimal in my code"**

Comment: I think you didn't check properly. in on blur while you focus out from the input field value will automatically trim and set only two digits. for example: if you add 92.78787878 after your focus out it will set to 92.78 next all the digits will trimmed..