# Missing trailing 0 on amounts like $20.00 for monetary calculations with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my calculations have .00 at the end of each amount. The app I'm building will be doing print outs for checks. Right now if an amount is $20.50 cents it's displayed at $20.5 which is not acceptable for checks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".input").keyup(function(){
        var val1 = +$(".washer").val();
        var val2 = +$(".dryer").val();
        var val3 = +$(".multi").val();
        var val4 = +$(".deduct").val();
        Math.round($("#result").val(val1+val2));
        var wtf = val4.toFixed(2);
        $("#result_mtbp").val(Math.round((val1+val2)*(val3)*100)/(100));
        $("#result_netp").val(Math.round((val1+val2)*(val3-val4)*100)/100);
      });
    });
</script>
```

I've perused through other solutions but cannot figure out how to implement them.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use .toFixed(2) - or more elaborate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029698/295783

Comment: OP is already using that. But in the wrong place.

Comment: I tried it at the end of the $("#result_mtbp").val(Math.round((val1+val2)*(val3)*100)/(100)) but it didn't calculate with it :(

Comment: Try: `$("#result_mtbp").val(((val1+val2)*(val3)).toFixed(2));`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp your solution works!!! Thx a milli!!!!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Sorry missed it because it was not at the end