# How to ROUND Decimal in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {

    $('.total_result').text(

      $('select[name=attendance]').val() * 0.25 + $('select[name=tardiness]').val() * 0.10 + $('select[name=rules]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=case]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=productivity]').val() * 0.15 + $('select[name=qa]').val() * 0.15 + $('select[name=utilization]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=schedule]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=fcr]').val() * 0.10 + $('select[name=aht]').val() * 0.05)
    ;

  });

});
```

I have an issue with my final code. I need to round the decimal.
I'm using onchange that will auto calculate.
Much appreciated. TIA

Comment: [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: [Number.prototype.toPrecision()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.toFixed(2); method is Used to round value.

in you example it will be like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {

    $('.total_result').text(($('select[name=attendance]').val() * 0.25 + $('select[name=tardiness]').val() * 0.10 + $('select[name=rules]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=case]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=productivity]').val() * 0.15 + $('select[name=qa]').val() * 0.15 + $('select[name=utilization]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=schedule]').val() * 0.05 + $('select[name=fcr]').val() * 0.10 + $('select[name=aht]').val() * 0.05).toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

Reference [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Comment: @jackflick Try this

Comment: .toFixed(2);  accept a parameter, in this case 2, for Numbers after decimal. in case alert("123.456789".toFixed(3)); will alert "123.456"

Comment: it worked Faraz! You're so amazing! I was trying the .toFixed(2) but it's not working for me and you did it just like that. :)
Thank you very much!