# HTML input type number value rounded to two decimal places in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using react to control the value. Is the option of rounding the value to two decimal places in HTML `input` type number? I have step `0.166666666`, but in HTML input view I'd like to display: `0.17` instead of `0.166666666666`, `0.33` instead of `0.333333333333` and so on...

I do not want to change the `value` of input, I would like to change only the Input view not `value`. `toFixed` won't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `toFixed(2)` function.

```
0.166666666666.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I can't because the step will be wrong, i would like to modified only VIEW not value

Comment: You can use this code `{value.toFixed(2)}` in your JSX view. then it will be modified only in VIEW, not value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use toFixed(2); function of javascript. For ex:-

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `toFixed(2)` to round it.

This will round `0.166666666666` to `0.17`, and `0.333333333333` to `0.33`.

If for example, you need `0.16` to be `0.166666666666` in your logic, only use `toFixed(2)` for the part of your code that will update what's visible in the input.