# When the result is round (1.10 1.30) does not display the 2nd decimal How do I do it?

Tags: javascript

My program (which uses Math.round) does not display the second decimal when the result is round (ex: 1.10, 1.30) while yes when the result is not round (ex: 1.24, 2.47). How to change this?

```
function calcAmount2() {
  var userAmount2 = document.getElementById("amount2").value;
  if (userAmount2 = Number(amount2.value)) {
    document.getElementById("marginAmount2").textContent =
      Math.round(userAmount2 * 3) / 100 + "€";
  }
}
```

(expected)1.10, 1.30 instead of (actually) 1.1 1.3

Comment: JavaScript does not have significant places. You can use toFixed()... too lazy to find the dupe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

`(Math.round(userAmount2 * 3) / 100).toFixed(2) + "€";`

toFixed sets the number to always have 2 decimals.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain your answer and add relevant references.

Comment: Bravo JensW! Simple and efficient. You are a best.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

You want to use `.toFixed(2)` it seems, though be aware the result will be a `String`.

Comment: Yes! pmiller3. Short and precise, if my english is good. You are a "one" guy.

Comment: Thank you @PhilippeDelestan! Be sure to upvote and choose an answer as well - all three here seem worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how specific your answer has to be, but I would recommend you to use this instead:

```
const res = Number(Math.round(userAmount2 +'e2')+'e-2');
```

This is because toFixed has the rounding problem for some values such as 21.005.

Let me prove it to you over here:

```js
    
console.log(Number(Math.round(20.005 +'e2')+'e-2'));
console.log(20.005.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: You're right, Gojun! There is problem of rounded value with 3 decimals. But, we can see as cool with euro, sometimes only. So, i willtest youre solution but i'm not understand this code. what is signification of "e2" and e-2"? I'm a beginner in javascript and i prefere when i understand what i doThanks a lot.

Comment: @PhilippeDelestan ah, I must have missed out that part on `e`. e in scientific/numeric notation refers to the number, times 10 to the power of the suffix! Therefore, `e2` means x10^2, and `e-2` means x10^-2.

Comment: I am essentially 'scaling' the number by two figures (x100) across the decimal point, rounding the value, followed by multiplying it back by (10^-2), in order to avoid all that floating point issues.

Comment: Yes, i understand very well. Thank you, Gojun.