# Javascript floating issue with addition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following value which give wrong total.

```
let a = 86.2500;
let b = 32.3550;
alert(a+b);  //return 118.60499999999999  , expected 118.605
alert((a+b).toFixed(2))  //return 118.60   , expected 118.61
```

When I calculate above value with my calculator it give my expected result but javascript give me unexpected result. Why and what is solution to get expected result?

https://jsfiddle.net/vnu9fyb8/1/

Comment: @Sadikhasan This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/21323330/2943218

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/46jrd71t/

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie If you have calculator please calculate it what you get and let me know. Are you getting my expected result? If I am wrong then correct me to get my expected result.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588019#588019), which this duplicates. For exhaustive details see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: One of the numbers cannot be represented precisely as binary value. You have the same issue in base 10 with `1/3`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the result:

```
let a = 86.2500;
let b = 32.3550;
alert((a+b).toFixed(3));
var digit = parseFloat((a+b).toFixed(3)).toFixed(2);
alert(digit);
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

*toFixed(2)* cannot make it become 118.61 because of the full result is *118.60499999999999* so "6049" in front of *0* is number 4. *4* can't be floored up to be *5*, but if in front of *0* is number *5* it sure will be floored up to 118.61.

So this can't become 118.61. 
You can refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)