# Image-Chart ChartJs Ticks Callback not Working?

Tags: chart.js, image-charts

Trying to understand what is not working with Image Charts on this URL?

[https://image-charts.com/chart.js/2.8.0?bkg=white&c={"type":"line","data":{"datasets":[{"type":"line","fill":false,"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 24, 1, 1)","borderColor":"rgba(255, 24, 1, 1)","pointRadius":0,"data":[67.0,65.0,70.0,81.0,83.0,81.0,79.0,74.0,78.0,77.0],"label":"Output"}],"labels":["00","05","10","15","20","25","30"]},"options":{"tooltips":{"intersect":false},"scales":{"xAxes":[{"gridLines":{"display":false},"ticks":{"callback":function(value, index, values) { return '' + value;}}}],"yAxes":[{"gridLines":{"display":false}}]}}}](https://image-charts.com/chart.js/2.8.0?bkg=white&c=%7B%22type%22:%22line%22,%22data%22:%7B%22datasets%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22line%22,%22fill%22:false,%22backgroundColor%22:%22rgba(255,%2024,%201,%201)%22,%22borderColor%22:%22rgba(255,%2024,%201,%201)%22,%22pointRadius%22:0,%22data%22:%5B67.0,65.0,70.0,81.0,83.0,81.0,79.0,74.0,78.0,77.0%5D,%22label%22:%22Output%22%7D%5D,%22labels%22:%5B%2200%22,%2205%22,%2210%22,%2215%22,%2220%22,%2225%22,%2230%22%5D%7D,%22options%22:%7B%22tooltips%22:%7B%22intersect%22:false%7D,%22scales%22:%7B%22xAxes%22:%5B%7B%22gridLines%22:%7B%22display%22:false%7D,%22ticks%22:%7B%22callback%22:function(value,%20index,%20values)%20%7B%20return%20%27%27%20+%20value;%7D%7D%7D%5D,%22yAxes%22:%5B%7B%22gridLines%22:%7B%22display%22:false%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D)

JSON:

```
{"type":"line","data":{"datasets":[{"type":"line","fill":false,"data":[59.0,57.0,57.0,58.0,57.0,56.0,57.0,55.0,62.0,63.0,62.0,62.0,69.0,63.0,62.0,61.0,62.0,62.0,66.0,69.0,72.0,72.0,75.0,82.0,84.0,85.0,84.0,81.0,91.0,90.0,87.0,87.0,89.0,90.0,90.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,83.0,83.0,82.0,81.0,85.0,89.0,85.0,83.0,87.0,81.0,81.0,81.0,91.0,90.0,81.0,87.0,83.0,98.0,90.0,81.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,92.0,90.0,91.0,90.0,88.0,81.0,83.0,91.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,87.0,88.0,91.0,88.0,86.0,86.0,87.0,86.0,91.0,90.0,91.0,92.0,91.0,91.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,95.0,94.0,92.0,92.0,91.0,88.0,88.0,90.0,88.0,90.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,88.0,91.0,88.0,91.0,94.0,90.0,90.0,88.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,86.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,88.0,79.0,74.0,83.0,85.0,83.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,83.0,90.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,91.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,83.0,85.0,87.0,85.0,86.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,86.0,91.0,92.0,88.0,85.0,87.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,92.0,88.0,83.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,90.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,91.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,86.0,90.0,87.0,90.0,90.0,94.0,92.0,91.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,91.0,92.0,90.0,86.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,88.0,91.0,90.0,90.0,91.0,91.0,87.0,90.0,92.0,87.0,86.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,92.0,92.0,81.0,78.0,79.0,83.0,86.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,85.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,87.0,86.0,88.0,90.0,91.0,90.0,95.0,97.0,98.0,95.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,98.0,95.0,95.0,108.0,95.0,95.0,95.0,91.0,78.0,83.0,82.0,92.0,89.0,88.0,85.0,86.0,94.0,94.0,97.0,99.0,99.0,97.0,95.0,91.0,92.0,94.0,95.0,92.0,94.0,94.0,95.0,92.0,94.0,94.0,95.0,95.0,92.0,94.0,97.0,95.0,95.0,94.0,102.0,104.0,99.0,98.0,95.0,94.0,91.0,94.0,94.0,91.0,92.0,91.0,92.0,97.0,94.0,92.0,91.0,97.0,95.0,109.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,110.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,105.0,102.0,102.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,105.0,107.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,104.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,105.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,110.0,112.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,105.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,112.0,117.0,110.0,109.0,116.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,109.0,104.0,112.0,116.0,114.0,116.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,109.0,105.0,112.0,114.0,110.0,110.0,114.0,116.0,112.0,107.0,112.0,107.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,114.0,110.0,110.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,116.0,117.0,117.0,117.0,114.0,114.0,109.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,114.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,114.0,112.0,109.0,114.0,110.0,112.0,114.0,116.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,119.0,121.0,119.0,117.0,114.0,110.0,114.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,105.0,104.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,105.0,102.0,105.0,102.0,107.0,104.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,110.0,112.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,107.0,112.0,110.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,114.0,112.0,109.0,107.0,112.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,110.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,112.0,114.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,107.0,116.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,107.0,95.0,94.0,80.0,83.0,85.0,92.0,98.0,100.0,98.0,98.0,97.0,100.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,117.0,98.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,119.0,104.0,91.0,88.0,95.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,109.0,105.0,100.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,105.0,104.0,105.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,104.0,104.0,109.0,105.0,104.0,114.0,116.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,112.0,107.0,112.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,102.0,105.0,107.0,109.0,112.0,109.0,107.0,104.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,110.0,110.0,109.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,105.0,102.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,104.0,104.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,114.0,117.0,112.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,121.0,117.0,117.0,112.0,114.0,116.0,110.0,109.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,100.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,105.0,107.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,104.0,105.0,104.0,100.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,98.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,100.0,100.0,98.0,100.0,100.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,105.0,107.0,112.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,116.0,110.0,107.0,107.0,116.0,110.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,110.0,116.0,116.0,119.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,110.0,114.0,112.0,110.0,116.0,109.0,110.0,110.0,116.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,114.0,109.0,109.0,105.0,105.0,102.0,109.0,109.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,104.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,105.0,112.0,114.0,112.0,114.0,116.0,118.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,116.0,122.0,118.0,116.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,116.0,118.0,118.0,120.0,118.0,115.0,109.0,111.0,116.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,120.0,118.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,116.0,115.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,111.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,109.0,124.0,120.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,118.0,115.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,113.0,99.0,96.0,104.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,118.0,116.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,115.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,120.0,116.0,120.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,111.0,106.0,107.0,113.0,111.0,115.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,113.0,107.0,109.0,115.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,116.0,111.0,106.0,111.0,107.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,111.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,115.0,113.0,111.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,111.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,115.0,116.0,116.0,116.0,113.0,113.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,109.0,100.0,96.0,89.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,109.0,106.0,111.0,109.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,113.0,109.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,102.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,109.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,102.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,106.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,107.0,104.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,116.0,116.0,115.0,107.0,107.0,113.0,109.0,106.0,102.0,104.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,109.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,97.0,99.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,100.0,99.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,99.0,99.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,100.0,99.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,104.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,106.0,116.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,106.0,106.0,111.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,99.0,99.0,100.0,99.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,100.0,97.0,99.0,97.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,99.0,97.0,99.0,97.0,99.0,96.0,97.0,96.0,97.0,96.0,100.0,104.0,100.0,104.0,102.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,99.0,113.0,115.0,109.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,124.0,124.0,115.0,118.0,116.0,115.0,113.0,122.0,120.0,116.0,122.0,118.0,118.0,120.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,115.0,116.0,113.0,115.0,118.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,113.0,118.0,122.0,122.0,118.0,118.0,122.0,120.0,118.0,113.0,115.0,115.0,111.0,120.0,60.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,99.0,100.0,96.0,99.0,102.0,109.0,102.0,104.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,102.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,111.0,106.0,104.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,104.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,106.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,115.0,109.0,116.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,116.0,120.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,115.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,116.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,111.0,109.0,115.0,128.0,128.0,120.0,120.0,120.0,115.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,118.0,120.0,120.0,124.0,115.0,118.0,113.0,111.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,111.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,115.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,120.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,116.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,116.0,118.0,106.0,99.0,89.0,97.0,99.0,100.0,107.0,104.0],"label":"Output"}]},"options":{}}
```

Comment: As an alternative, you may want to try https://quickchart.io which can handle Javascript functions (note that you will have to URL-encode your `c` param)

Answer (score 1):

Image-Charts founder here, indeed for security and reliability reasons our Charts API does not currently support JavaScript functions.

PS: we might add JavaScript function support later on based on customer demands though :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you why `image-charts.com` is not accepting your request but from Chart.js point of view, your chart configuration looks almost fine, including the `ticks.callback`. The only problem I can see is that `data.labels` does not contain the same number of items as `data.datasets[0].data`.

The presumed problem with your x-axis `ticks.callback` is that you return the `string` value combined with an empty string, which produces the same result as without `ticks.callback`.

```
"ticks": {
   "callback": function(value, index, values) {
     return '' + value;
   }
 }
```

> Not sure what you expected but please be aware that the x-axis ticks are the ones that appear at the bottom of the chart.

In case you want to format the tick labels on the y-axis, you could use the following (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726662/2358409):

```
"yAxes": [{
  "ticks": {
    "callback": value => value.toFixed(1)
  },
  ...
```

Please take a look at the following runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    "datasets": [{
      "type": "line",
      "fill": false,
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 24, 1, 1)",
      "borderColor": "rgba(255, 24, 1, 1)",
      "pointRadius": 0,
      "data": [67.0, 65.0, 70.0, 81.0, 83.0, 81.0, 79.0, 74.0, 78.0, 77.0],
      "label": "Output"
    }],
    "labels": ["00", "05", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30"]
  },
  "options": {
    "tooltips": {
      "intersect": false
    },
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [{
        "gridLines": {
          "display": false
        }        
      }],
      "yAxes": [{
        "ticks": {
          "callback": value => value.toFixed(1)
        },
        "gridLines": {
          "display": false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is that its not valid json.

As to my knowledge JSON doesnt support functions so you will have to remove to callback and make sure the ticks are already correct before you send your data to image-chart.

If you remove the callback function it works fine: [https://image-charts.com/chart.js/2.8.0?bkg=white&c={%22type%22:%22line%22,%22data%22:{%22datasets%22:[{%22type%22:%22line%22,%22fill%22:false,%22backgroundColor%22:%22rgba(255,%2024,%201,%201)%22,%22borderColor%22:%22rgba(255,%2024,%201,%201)%22,%22pointRadius%22:0,%22data%22:[67.0,65.0,70.0,81.0,83.0,81.0,79.0,74.0,78.0,77.0],%22label%22:%22Output%22}],%22labels%22:[%2200%22,%2205%22,%2210%22,%2215%22,%2220%22,%2225%22,%2230%22]},%22options%22:{%22tooltips%22:{%22intersect%22:false},%22scales%22:{%22xAxes%22:[{%22gridLines%22:{%22display%22:false}}],%22yAxes%22:[{%22gridLines%22:{%22display%22:false}}]}}}](https://image-charts.com/chart.js/2.8.0?bkg=white&c=%7B%22type%22:%22line%22,%22data%22:%7B%22datasets%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22line%22,%22fill%22:false,%22backgroundColor%22:%22rgba(255,%2024,%201,%201)%22,%22borderColor%22:%22rgba(255,%2024,%201,%201)%22,%22pointRadius%22:0,%22data%22:%5B67.0,65.0,70.0,81.0,83.0,81.0,79.0,74.0,78.0,77.0%5D,%22label%22:%22Output%22%7D%5D,%22labels%22:%5B%2200%22,%2205%22,%2210%22,%2215%22,%2220%22,%2225%22,%2230%22%5D%7D,%22options%22:%7B%22tooltips%22:%7B%22intersect%22:false%7D,%22scales%22:%7B%22xAxes%22:%5B%7B%22gridLines%22:%7B%22display%22:false%7D%7D%5D,%22yAxes%22:%5B%7B%22gridLines%22:%7B%22display%22:false%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D)

If you really need the functionality of the callback you will have to implement the normal version of the lib, in there your original config is working as intended.