# Convert string to number but maintain zeros in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, numbers, parseint

I am working with GBP currency in Javascript and converting a string currency to a number like the following: `Number('1.20')` will give me `1.2`. But I want to maintain the `0` when converting to a `number` type. Is this possible? This is the result that I want : `1.20`. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: maintain how? where does the missing 0 cause issue?

Comment: It seems you are confusing number *values* with their *representation*. `1.2` and `1.20` are the same number *value*. If you need the trailing zero for *display* purposes then see [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1726630/218196)

Comment: Use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) for currencies.

Comment: Both are the same numbers. Even if you use toFixed, it'll be converted to string & if you try to convert it to Number, it'll strip zero again.

Comment: No, this is not possible, numbers in JS are [IEEE754 floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), and the standard doesn't include leading or trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to work with Currency in Javascript is to use the `Intl.NumberFormat`. For course, the output will be of the type: 'String'

The output will take care of the number of decimal places depending on the Currency you specify. In your case `GBP` so it will be 2 decimal places.

Example:

```js
const number = 1.2;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' }).format(number));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can control the decimals like this in Javascript:

```
let num = 1.204;
let n = num.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: this doesn't keep the trailing zeros